# Apex Trigger Optimization?

Tags: apex, trigger

`enter code here`I have a trigger which sends out an email to a Responsibility Lead (basically an user) , when an responsibility lead in planned revenue (custom object) is not the same as of logged in user.

I have written the below piece of code. However wanted to see if it needs any further optimization.

```java
trigger SendEmail on Revenue__c (after insert,after update) {
    List<String> emailIds = new List<String>();
    Set<Id> plnId = new Set<Id>();
    User usr = [select id from User where id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    List<Id> empIds = new List<Id>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        for(Revenue__c p: [SELECT Id,Employee__c,Employee__r.T1C_Base__User__c, FROM Revenue__c WHERE id IN :Trigger.new AND Employee__r.T1C_Base__User__c!=:usr.id]){
            empIds.add(p.Employee__r.User__c);
           
         
        }
    }
    else If (Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Revenue__c plnrev :Trigger.new){
            if(trigger.oldMap.get(plnrev.Id).Employee__c != plnrev.Employee__c){
                 for(Revenue__c p: [SELECT Id,Employee__c,Employee__r.User__c FROM Revenue__c WHERE id =:plnrev.Id])
                {
                    empIds.add(p.Employee__r.User__c);
                    
                } 
            }        
        }
    }
    List<Employee__c> e = [SELECT Id, __c FROM Employee__c WHERE User__c =:empIds ];
    for (Employee__c emp : e) {
        emailIds.add(emp.Email__c);
        if (emp.User__c != usr.id) {
        EmailUtils.sendEmail(emailIds,plnId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You should consider using a trigger framework

To move the logic out of your trigger itself.

This has a few benefits, like making testing easier (and more independent) and letting you be able to call this code from somewhere else. When your logic is inside of a triggger, it can only be called by causing the trigger to be executed (via DML)

There are several frameworks you can explore, like [Kevin O'Hara's](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework), the [Lightweight Apex Trigger Framework](http://chrisaldridge.com/triggers/lightweight-apex-trigger-framework/) from Chris Aldridge, [Hari Krishnan's](https://krishhari.wordpress.com/tag/salesforce-trigger-architecture/), and likely others.

#### Your query on the `User` object does nothing

You're using `Userinfo.getUserId()` to get an Id to let you query for the User Id that you already have.

The query isn't doing anything for you here (except using a precious query that could be better used elsewhere).

#### You seem to be sending emails in a loop

```
for (T1C_Base__Employee__c emp : e) {
    emailIds.add(emp.T1C_Base__Email__c);
    if (emp.T1C_Base__User__c != usr.id) {
      SC_GBM_EmailUtils.sendEmailPlanRev(emailIds,plnId);
    }
}
```

Looks like you may have meant to call `SC_GBM_EmailUtils.sendEmailPlanRev()` outside of the loop. We're only allowed 10 `sendEmail` calls in a transaction, so this is really something you should get a collection for and call outside of all loops.

#### You have a query in a loop

```
else If (Trigger.isUpdate){
    for(Planned_Revenue__c plnrev :Trigger.new){
        if(trigger.oldMap.get(plnrev.Id).Employee__c != plnrev.Employee__c){
             for(Planned_Revenue__c p: [SELECT Id,Employee__c,Employee__r.T1C_Base__User__c,GBM_Client_Plan__c FROM Planned_Revenue__c WHERE id =:plnrev.Id])
            {
```

Use the iterate-gather-query approach to make this nested loop (with a query) into two separate loops so that you don't waste queries. [This recent canonical-qa question should help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records).

Comment: might be a good idea to point out the SOQL query in a loop in the "else If (Trigger.isUpdate){" flow.

Comment: @PhilW Right, didn't see that on my first reading. Edited answer.