# How to avoid using SOQL with in For loop?

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

When i run the test code, it throws me message "System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101". How do i avoid using too many SOQL in this code.

```
    trigger GetObjLabel on Task (before insert, before update) {
    for(Task t : trigger.new){
     if(t.whatID != null){
      List<HOA__c> HOAList= [select id,name from HOA__c where id =: t.whatID];
      LIST<Patient_Event__c> SafetyEventList=[select id, name from Patient_Event__c where id=:t.whatID];
      List<Review__c> SEreviewList=[Select id, Name from Review__c where id=:t.whatId];
      List<Patient_Satisfaction__c> PRList=[Select id, Name from Patient_Satisfaction__c where 
      id=:t.whatId];
      List<Root_Cause_Analysis__c> RCAList=[Select id, Name from Root_Cause_Analysis__c where 
      id=:t.whatId];
        if(HOAList.size() > 0){
        for(HOA__c o : HOAList){
                t.Object_Label__c= 'HOA' + '('+o.Name+ ')'; //This will give output as HOA(<HOA. name>)
             }
          }
          else if(SafetyEventList.size() > 0){
             for(Patient_Event__c a : SafetyEventList){
                t.Object_Label__c= 'Safety Event' + '('+a.Name+ ')';  
             }
          }
           else if(SEreviewList.size() > 0){
             for(Review__c r : SEreviewList){
                t.Object_Label__c= 'Safety Event Review' + '('+r.Name+ ')'; 
             }
          }
              else if(PRList.size() > 0){
             for(Patient_Satisfaction__c r : PRList){
                t.Object_Label__c= 'Patient Relations' + '('+r.Name+ ')'; 
             }
          }
              else if(RCAList.size() > 0){
             for(Root_Cause_Analysis__c r : RCAList){
                t.Object_Label__c= 'RCA' + '('+r.Name+ ')';
             }
          }
          else{
               t.Object_Label__c= null;
          }
      }
   }
        
}
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE; you have soql inside for loop . Please read up on apex bulkification patterns

Comment: This is a common enough question that the community has put together a canonical question and answer for this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use the [Aggregate-Query-Update pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html). Here's one possible revision that should do what you want:

```
trigger GetObjLabel on Task (before insert, before update) {
    Map<Id, sObject> whatIds = new Map<Id, sObject>();
    Set<sObjectType> types = new Set<sObjectType>();
    for(Task record: Trigger.new) {
        whatIds.put(record.WhatId, null);
        if(record.WhatId != null) {
            types.add(record.WhatId.getSObjectType());
        }
    }
    if(types.contains(HOA__c.sObjectType)) {
        whatIds.putAll([SELECT Name FROM HOA__c WHERE Id = :whatIds.keySet()]);
    }
    if(types.contains(Patient_Event__c.sObjectType)) {
        whatIds.putAll([SELECT Name FROM Patient_Event__c WHERE Id = :whatIds.keySet()]);
    }
    if(types.contains(Review__c.sObjectType)) {
        whatIds.putAll([SELECT Name FROM Review__c WHERE Id = :whatIds.keySet()]);
    }
    if(types.contains(Patient_Satisfaction__c.sObjectType)) {
        whatIds.putAll([SELECT Name FROM Patient_Satisfaction__c WHERE Id = :whatIds.keySet()]);
    }
    if(types.contains(Root_Cause_Analysis__c.sObjectType)) {
        whatIds.putAll([SELECT Name FROM Root_Cause_Analysis__c WHERE Id = :whatIds.keySet()]);
    }
    for(Task record: Trigger.new) {
        sObject whatRecord = whatIds.get(record.WhatId);
        switch on whatRecord {
            when HOA__c hoaRecord {
                record.Object_Label__c= 'HOA' + '('+hoaRecord.Name+ ')';
            }
            when Patient_Event__c patientEventRecord {
                record.Object_Label__c= 'Safety Event' + '('+patientEventRecord.Name+ ')';
            }
            when Review__c reviewRecord {
                record.Object_Label__c= 'Safety Event Review' + '('+reviewRecord.Name+ ')';
            }
            when Patient_Satisfaction__c patientSatisfactionRecord {
                record.Object_Label__c= 'Patient Relations' + '('+patientSatisfactionRecord.Name+ ')';
            }
            when Root_Cause_Analysis__c rootCauseAnalysisRecord {
                record.Object_Label__c= 'RCA' + '('+rootCauseAnalysisRecord.Name+ ')';
            }
            when else {
                record.Object_Label__c = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This Canonical QA](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) nicely covers most questions related to bulkifying queries.

There's another wrinkle here, though, because you are working with `Task`, which has a polymorphic `What` relationship. You do not need to write multiple queries for different objects, because *you can query for `Name` through a polymorphic relationship*.

```
SELECT What.Name, What.Type FROM Task WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new
```

would work in an `after insert` context (not here, in `before insert`) and would allow you to query the newly-inserted Tasks with the two data points you need (the Related To name and the type of the Related To object) in a single SOQL query.

You can then iterate over this query and build up a `List<Task>` of records to update based on the relationship data queried, using `t.What.Type` to decide what object name to reference and including `t.What.Name` in the resulting string.

Yes, it will incur one round of trigger recursion because you'll have to `update` in `after` context, but it may make up for that with the simplicity of the query and savings on SOQL limits - and you'll have to write a lot less conditional logic.

If more data is required from the Related To object, you can now use [polymorphic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm) to access that via a single query rooted at `Task`.

Comment: Thanks David. This is helpful