# Apex trigger , loop challenge

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

```
trigger CheckSecretInformation on Case (after insert, before update) {
    
    String childCaseSubject = 'Warning : Parent case may contain secret info';
    //Step 1: Create a collection containing each of our secret keywords
    Set<String> secretKeywords = new set<String>();
    secretKeywords.add('Credit Card');
    secretKeywords.add('Social Security');
    secretKeywords.add('SSN');
    secretKeywords.add('Passport');
    secretKeywords.add('Bodyweight');
    
    //Step 2: Check to see if our case contains any of the secret keywords
    List<case> casesWithSecretInfo = new List<case>();
    for(Case myCase: trigger.new){
        if(myCase.Subject != childCaseSubject){  
            for(String Keyword : secretKeywords){
                if(myCase.Description != null && myCase.Description.ContainsIgnoreCase(Keyword)){
                    casesWithSecretInfo.add(myCase);
                    System.debug('Case ' + myCase.Id + 'Include secret keyword' + keyword);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Step 3: Create child case
            for(case caseWithSecretInfo : casesWithSecretInfo){
                Case childCase        = new Case();
                childCase.Subject     = childCaseSubject;
                childCase.Priority    = 'High';
                childCase.Description = 'One of the secret keywords were found containing atleast one 
                                            from these' + secretKeywords; 
                childCase.IsEscalated = true;
                childCase.ParentId    = caseWithSecretInfo.id;
                insert childCase;
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to replace the lines "secretKeyword" term, which is a List to specific values which are in list.
childCase.Description = 'One of the secret keywords were found containing atleast one from these' +
secretKeywords;
For eg:- If in description there is only 'passport' and 'credit card'. Then it must show only those two values not whole list.
Please help me gys, I am new to apex.

Comment: you should be after insert/after update; not before update; your DML is in a loop which is not best practice and leads to problems with bulk updates. Read up on Apex maps

Comment: ok but using after update, then what. I want to replace the "kewords" list with just the values which are occurring Dont want to display the whole list. Any answers regarding challenge.

Comment: Parag -- in general, until you bulkify your trigger properly, you may not get sufficient support from the Community. For reference, see [Trailhead on Apex/Bulkification](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk)

Comment: Also see [this canonical Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) that covers bulkification patterns.

Comment: Actually bro , I am following the online course of David.K,Liu (sfdc99 blogger) on plural sight . He has said to verify, if you have understand everything properly, complete this tough task without bulkifying it. and then the next module is of bukifying the triggers. Thats why I am getting some Ideas to complete it.

Comment: Please do not say things like "actually bro" - it is inappropriately over-familiar language IMHO. I would also suggest that this isn't a particularly tough task, and that the approach of teaching you how not to implement a trigger is the wrong way to teach.