# SOQL query on non-related objects

Tags: soql

Account is a parent to Object B and Object C. Object B and Object C does not have any relationship.
From Object B I want to find Object C's fields(like name etc.,) using Account in a single SOQL query.
Below is the SOQL query:

`Select id, Account.Name from ObjB where Account.Name IN(select Account__c from ObjC)`.

In the inner query I am passing the Account__c, but I want to find the value of Name field from ObjC. Is this achievable in any way?

Comment: Yes, at least in some form it can be achieved (through, for example, a parent-child subquery on Account, or a child-to-parent query on Object C). If you [edit] your question with *what you've tried* and *where you're stuck*, it will be easier for the community to provide a specific answer.

Comment: Note that this [canonical Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) covers this sort of thing in the "I need data from indirectly related records based on one or more input record fields" scenario, showing how to do this for multiple fields. You have a simplified variant based just on the "Account" field.

Answer (score 1):

Your query as written

```
Select id, Account.Name from ObjB where Account.Name IN(select Account__c from ObjC
).
```

cannot source data from Object C, another child of Account. In fact, it shouldn't work at all, because you're performing a semi-join against a non-Id field.

You can however start the query from the Account level and perform two child subqueries:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM ObjC__r), (SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM ObjB__r)
FROM Account
WHERE Id = :yourIdVariable
```

given `yourIdVariable` defined in Apex as the Account that you want. You must make sure to query using the real relationship names for Objects B and C, which are defined on the relationship field in Setup and postfixed with `__r` if they are custom relationships.

Comment: Hi David, 
I want to query from the child object ie., ObjB instead of parent object. is that possible?

Comment: As stated above, no, you can't form the query exactly that way, but there are workable routes