# Bulkified Class?

Tags: apex, class, bulkification

I have a utility class for a trigger on a custom object that queries the custom object records for an account when one of the custom object records is updated and then sets a custom checkbox field on the Account to TRUE if all the custom object records contain one of the keywords listed in a Custom setting. If any of the records do not contain a keyword, the Account field is set to FALSE. It works fine for individual record updates, but I am having issues when mass uploading records for the custom object.  Is the utility class below "bulkified" to be able to handle mass uploads of records? I thought it was but maybe I'm missing something.  Any advice on changes to the below?

**Utility Class:**

```
public class TerritoryUtility {
    
    public static void updateTerritiry(List<Territories__c> newTerritoryList){
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Territories__c territorry : newTerritoryList){
            Account account = [SELECT Id,Terr_Impacted__c
                               FROM Account territory.Account__c];
            List<Territories__c> listTerritories = [SELECT Id, Notes__c, Reason__c
                                                  FROM Territories__c
                                                  WHERE Account__c =: account.Id];
            List<KeyWords__c> listKeyword = [SELECT Name FROM KeyWords__c];
            
            integer impact = 0;
            for(Territories__c terr2 :listTerritories){
                    for(KeyWords__c terrKey :listKeyword){
                        if((terr2.Notes__c != null && (terr2.Notes__c.contains(terrKey.Name) || terrr2.Notes__c.contains(terrKey.Name))) || (terr2.Reason__c != null && (terr2.eCW_Reason__c.contains(terrKey.Name) || terr2.Reason__c.contains(terrKey.Name)))){
                            impact += 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            }
            system.debug('@@@###-Impact: '+impact);
            if(impact < listTerritories.size()){
                account.Terr_Impacted__c = FALSE;
            }else{
                account.Terr_Impacted__c = TRUE;
            }
            update account;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is not bulkified. You are performing both SOQL and DML in a loop:

```
    for(Territories__c territorry : newTerritoryList){
        Account account = [SELECT Id,Terr_Impacted__c
                           FROM Account territory.Account__c];
        List<Territories__c> listTerritories = [SELECT Id, Notes__c, Reason__c
                                              FROM Territories__c
                                              WHERE Account__c =: account.Id];
        List<KeyWords__c> listKeyword = [SELECT Name FROM KeyWords__c];

        // ...

         update account;
```

The query against `KeyWords__c` is not limited by iteration variables and so can simply be lifted and moved outside the loop.

The queries against `Account` and `Territories__c` need to be bulkified. Additionally, it appears that the `Territories__c` query could be rewritten as a subquery, saving one SOQL and likely simplifying the revised code.

The syntax of the Account query is not correct as written. However, the patterns explained in [How do I bulkify queries for directly or indirectly related records?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records)
 will allow you to address it.

Once you bulkify your queries, you'll need to accumulate a collection (probably a `Map<Id, Account>`) of records you wish to update and perform a single `update` DML against that collection outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look there