# Refer to parent object in Trigger

Tags: trigger, query, map, parent-to-child

I have a trigger on Contact which gets fetches 2 custom field from account (customfieldaccount) and contact(customfieldcontact).

I am having null value for the custom field on the Account object.

Here is the code;

```
trigger DeleteTrigger on Contact (before delete) {

    for(Contact ctact : Trigger.Old){
        if (customfieldcontact == 'something' && ctact.Account.customfieldaccount == 'something' ){
            Trigger.oldMap.get(ctact.Id).addError('Error message');
        } else if (customfieldcontact == 'something' && ctact.Account.customfieldaccount == 'something'){
            Trigger.oldMap.get(ctact.Id).addError('Error message');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I bulkify queries for directly or indirectly related records?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) Specifically look at scenario 2 "I just need data from directly related records but I'm in a trigger".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationship objects (lookups) are not available in triggers by default. You need to query them and get it.

More info [here](https://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/23/relationship-lookup-objects-in-triggers-are-null/)