# If Contact is created without a mailing address, copy related Account address

Tags: trigger

When a user creates a new Contact from the LFO sidebar the Contact address does not prefill with the related Account address (like it would from desktop UI). We want the Contact to take the address from the Account, on creation, if it has been left blank.

This is my attempt. Any tips/advice would be much appreciated.

Updated using linked advice:

```
trigger ContactAddress on Contact (before insert) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        
        if (c.AccountId     != null &&
        c.MailingStreet      = null &&
        c.MailingCity        = null &&
        c.MailingState       = null &&
        c.MailingPostalCode  = null &&
        c.MailingCountry     = null) {
            
        accountIds.put(c.AccountId);
    }
}


// Get the Accounts' address and make the data efficient to use
Map<Id, Account> accsById = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry  FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN :accountIds]);

// Now process the Contacts to set their Address to be the same as their Account's
for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
    if (c.AccountId != null) {
        Account acc = accsById(c.AccountId);  
        
          c.MailingStreet     = acc.BillingStreet;
          c.MailingCity       = acc.BillingCity;
          c.MailingState      = acc.BillingState;
          c.MailingPostalCode = acc.BillingPostalCode;
          c.MailingCountry    = acc.BillingCountry;
        
        
        }
    }
}
```

original:

```
*trigger UpdateContactAddress on Contact (before insert) {
     List<Contact> newContactList = new list<Contact>();
     
     for (Contact c : Trigger.new){
                  
         If(
          c.MailingStreet     &&
          c.MailingCity       &&
          c.MailingState      &&
          c.MailingPostalCode &&
          c.MailingCountry    = null){
          contact ccreate = new contact(id = c.id);
          ccreate.MailingStreet     = c.Account.BillingStreet;
          ccreate.MailingCity       = c.Account.BillingCity;
          ccreate.MailingState      = c.Account.BillingState;
          ccreate.MailingPostalCode = c.Account.BillingPostalCode;
          ccreate.MailingCountry    = c.Account.BillingCountry;
          newContactList.add(ccreate);
      }
    }
  
         
            update newContactList;
 }*
```

The error: "Line 7 Expression cannot be assigned".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a before trigger you can update fields of the trigger context objects without performing a DML operation (remove the new contact list and get rid of the `update` statement). Such changes simply get included into the objects for which the trigger was invoked.

You also need to ensure you query the related accounts, since triggers do not populate details of such objects.

Take a look at the ["I just need data from directly related records but I'm in a trigger" scenario explanation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/321847/50252) of how to get the details of related objects.

The cleaned up trigger might be:

```
trigger ContactAddress on Contact (before insert) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.AccountId != null &&
                c.MailingStreet == null &&
                c.MailingCity == null &&
                c.MailingState == null &&
                c.MailingPostalCode == null &&
                c.MailingCountry == null) {
            accountIds.put(c.AccountId);
        }
    }

    // Get the Accounts' address and make the data efficient to use
    Map<Id, Account> accsById = new Map<Id, Account>([
            SELECT Id, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry
                    FROM Account
                    WHERE Id IN :accountIds
    ]);

    // Now process the Contacts to set their Address to be the same as their Account's
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.AccountId != null &&
                c.MailingStreet == null &&
                c.MailingCity == null &&
                c.MailingState == null &&
                c.MailingPostalCode == null &&
                c.MailingCountry == null) {
            Account acc = accsById.get(c.AccountId);

            c.MailingStreet = acc.BillingStreet;
            c.MailingCity = acc.BillingCity;
            c.MailingState = acc.BillingState;
            c.MailingPostalCode = acc.BillingPostalCode;
            c.MailingCountry = acc.BillingCountry;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you should actually put this code in a trigger helper class, to which you pass the trigger context variables, to allow you to test this code without having to actually perform any DML on the contacts to process.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I've updated it based on the advice under the section "I just need data from directly related records but I'm in a trigger". Thanks for linking, I definitely still have some work to do.

Comment: Hi, the updated code seems to have a spurious "}" closing the trigger after collecting the account IDs...? Also, the check for empty contact address is needed in both loops if you a) want to restrict the accounts set to accounts for contacts with no address and b) you want to only update contacts that have no address.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you Phil.