# Tier Pricing on opportunityLineItems

Tags: apex, trigger

My task is to change the sales price in Opportunity product when the particular price Book is choosed for eg(MRP Pricebook,Pongal Pricebook, Diwali PriceBook) for particular product via tier pricing (custom object)

I have written the code but my if condition while checking the pricebook it is not getting me the right sales price(Unit Price) for the particular product

MyCode is

```
trigger TierPricingOffers on OpportunityLineItem (before Insert,before Update)
{
    if(trigger.isBefore)
    {
        List<Pricebook2> PB=[SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Price_Book__c , From_Unit__c,Price__c FROM Tier_Pricings__r)FROM Pricebook2];
        List<Product2> PR=[SELECT Id,(SELECT Product__c,Price_Book__c,Price__c,To_Unit__c,From_Unit__c FROM Tier_Pricings__r)FROM Product2];
        List<PriceBookEntry> PE= [ Select Id, Name, Product2Id,Product2.Name, PriceBook2Id, PriceBook2.Name From PriceBookEntry];
        List<OpportunityLineItem> OLI=[SELECT Id,UnitPrice,Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItem];
        List<OpportunityLineItem> lstTesting = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

            if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)
            {
            for(Product2 a : PR )
                {
                    for(PriceBookEntry d:PE)
                    {
             
                        for(OpportunityLineItem PItem : trigger.new)
                             {
                               
                                if(a.id == PItem.product2Id)
                                {
                                    Decimal prdPrice;
                                   
                                   
                                    for(Tier_Price__c c : a.Tier_Pricings__r)
                                    {
                                        prdPrice = c.Price__c;
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                            if(c.Price_Book__c == d.PriceBook2Id )
                                            {
                                                System.debug('pricebook __c==='+c.Price_Book__c);
                                                System.debug('pricebook2 id==='+d.PriceBook2Id);
                                                System.debug('a======'+d.PriceBook2.Name);
                                                    if(d.PriceBook2.Name == 'MRP Price' || d.PriceBook2.Name == 'Diwali Offers' || d.PriceBook2.Name == 'Pongal Offers')
                                                    {
                                                        if (PItem.Quantity >= 1 && PItem.Quantity <= 100 && c.To_Unit__c >=1 && c.To_Unit__c <=100 )
                                                        {
                                                            System.debug('1-100======'+d.PriceBook2.Name);
                                                            System.debug('1-100 prd======'+prdPrice);
                                                            PItem.UnitPrice = prdPrice;
                                                        }
                                                    else if (PItem.Quantity >= 101 && PItem.Quantity <= 1000 && c.To_Unit__c >=101 && c.To_Unit__c <=1000 )
                                                        {
                                                        PItem.UnitPrice = prdPrice;
                                                        }
                                                    else if (PItem.Quantity >= 1001 && PItem.Quantity <= 10000 && c.To_Unit__c >=1001 && c.To_Unit__c <=10000 )
                                                        {
                                                        PItem.UnitPrice = prdPrice;
                                                        }
                                                       
                                                   
                                                    else
                                                       {
                                                       system.debug('====>');
                                                       }
                                                       insert lstTesting;
                                               } }    
                                }
                            }  
                        }        
                    }
                }
                               
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to format your code, and please use only relevant tags; this is not related to `salesforcedx` or `community`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is the same as your previous, now-deleted question: your `if`/`else` branches all do exactly the same thing.

It appears that you should be selecting a Pricing Tier based on Quantity and Pricebook, and applying only that *one* Pricing Tier to a specific item.

Instead, you are iterating over all Pricing Tiers for each Product, and then you are applying *every* Pricing Tier to *every* item in specific Pricebooks:

```
if (PItem.Quantity >= 1 && PItem.Quantity <= 100 && c.To_Unit__c >=1 && c.To_Unit__c <=100 ) {
    PItem.UnitPrice = prdPrice;
} else if (PItem.Quantity >= 101 && PItem.Quantity <= 1000 && c.To_Unit__c >=101 && c.To_Unit__c <=1000 ) {
    PItem.UnitPrice = prdPrice;
} else if (PItem.Quantity >= 1001 && PItem.Quantity <= 10000 && c.To_Unit__c >=1001 && c.To_Unit__c <=10000 ) {
    PItem.UnitPrice = prdPrice;
}
```

Notice that *every `if` statement has the same result*. This basically means that whichever Pricing Tier comes last in the query will "win", because it is applied last.

---

More generally, this code is disastrously inefficient, on the order of N^4, because you are using deeply inefficient *matrix search* operations, where you iterate over all elements of four different collections in nested `for` loops.

It is highly likely that you will hit CPU timeout exceptions, and it is hard for you to write your logic in a way that actually makes sense because the *only* structure you're using is loops.

What you need are Maps. For example, it looks to me like *one* piece you need to solve here is to be able to efficiently get the list of Pricing Tiers associated with an Opportunity Line Item's associated Product.

To do this efficiently, you can create a `Map<Id, List<Pricing_Tier__c>> pricingTiersByProduct2Id` that is keyed on the Product2 Id. You can then get the correct list of Pricing Tiers for a specific Opportunity Line Item by asking your Map instead of iterating, something like this:

```
pricingTiersByProduct2Id.get(PItem.Product2Id);
```

In the final version of your code, you'll probably have exactly two loops: one over Opportunity Line Items, and one over related Pricing Tiers, *of which you should apply only one* by checking that it actually applies to the current Opportunity Line Item. There's a little more optimization that could be done next, but that will get you most of the way there.

---

I wrote an article about this general problem of nested iteration, [Nested Iteration: A Quick Look at Computational Complexity in Apex](https://www.ktema.org/2019/11/04/quick-look-computational-complexity-apex/). We also have a great [canonical QA](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) that explores how to use Maps to access related data efficiently.

Neither of these pieces relates directly to your use case, but you *need to understand these principles* in order to successfully write the kind of logic you are building now.