# Delete sharing in a Trigger

Tags: trigger, soql, sharing

I have a trigger which create sharing when a record is created and delete sharings when records are deleted.

My problem is that I would like the request for the sharing to be basic and work when multiple records are deleted.

What i have now:

```
        List<AssignedResource> listAR = aRSel.selectUsersAndAccountFromServiceAppointments(setIdSAToRemoveSharing);
        Set<Id> setUserId = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> setAccountId = new Set<Id>();
        for(AssignedResource ar : listAR){
            setUserId.add(ar.ServiceResource.RelatedRecordId);
            setAccountId.add(ar.ServiceAppointment.AccountId);
        }

        List<AccountShare> accShare = [select Id from AccountShare where UserOrGroupId in: setUserId AND AccountId in: setAccountId];
        delete accShare;
```

My problem with the request for accShare is that it wont work the way it should if I delete multiple AssignedRessource (The object which will trigger the deletion of the sharing).

It will delete more due to the double IN that i use in my request.
E.G :

Let's say I have:
Record1 (R1) linked to Account1(A1) and User1(U1)
Record2 (R2) linked to Account2(A2) and User2(U2)
Record3 (R3) linked to Account2(A1) and User2(U2)

If i delete R1 and R2. R3 will be deleted aswell and that I don't want.

So is there a way to either add a field to the AccountShare Object so i can make a formula to have a field which is the pair I want to delete and request over that field ?
Is there any other solution to have multiples IN in an SOQL statement without those taking too much records?

In advance thank you.

Comment: Take a look at scenario 3 in [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) entitled "I need data from indirectly related records based on one or more input record fields" which should give you a big hint on the approach needed.

Comment: Yes!!! Absolutely awesome. I'm pretty sure I got everything I want with that. 
Thanks i'll test that Asap.

Comment: (Sorry, the second comment was automatically added when I voted to close your question as a "duplicate" just to keep SFSE tidy. Glad it looks like there's enough info for you to proceed.)