# Batch that does not update record, Duplicate Id in list

Tags: apex, batch

Alright, I've made progress, but I still get a fatal error on line 220

```
01:26:29:088 FATAL_ERROR System.ListException: Duplicate id in list: a0D1X000003tQ2IUAU
FATAL_ERROR Class.PRG_MAJ_Total.execute: line 220, column 1
```

Here is my updated code

```
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
      query = 'SELECT Id FROM PAX__C WHERE Pr_nom__c =\''+ 
      String.escapeSingleQuotes(Name)+'\'';
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List < PAX__c > scope) {


    PAX__c mainPax;
    PAX__c PaxMaj;
    List < Reglement__c > Reglements;
    Decimal Solde;
    Decimal Regle;

    List < Sous_ligne_de_facture__c > sousLignesDeFactureDuForfait = new List < Sous_ligne_de_facture__c > ();
    List < Sous_ligne_de_facture__c > sousLignesDeFactureDesOptions = new List < Sous_ligne_de_facture__c > ();
    Map < String, Ligne_de_facture__c > LignesDeFactureDesOptions = new Map < String, Ligne_de_facture__c > ();
    List < Pax__c > participants;
    List < Pax__c > roomMates;
    List < Pax__c > roomMates2;
    Decimal totalTTC = 0;

    Decimal acompte;
    Boolean acompteClient;
    Integer nbParticipants;
    Integer nbParticipantsForfait;
    Decimal ForfaitPU_HT = 0;
    Decimal taxesAeroportParPax = null;

    List < Element_projet__c > listAssurances = new List < Element_projet__c > ();

    Integer cpt1 = 0;
    Integer cpt2 = 0;
    Integer cpt3 = 0;

    String TourLeader;

    String IdeDossierProduit;

    List < Segment__c > listSegmentTransport = new List < Segment__c > ();

    List < Element_projet__c > listPrestations = new List < Element_projet__c > ();



    Map < Id, Id[] > DossierIdMap = new Map < Id, Id[] > ();

    List < PAX__c > DossierId = [SELECT Dossier_voyage__c, Id FROM Pax__c WHERE Id IN: scope];




    for (PAX__C j: DossierId) {
        if (DossierIdMap.containsKey(j.Dossier_voyage__c)) {
            Id[] ls = DossierIdMap.get(j.Dossier_voyage__c);
            ls.add(j.Id);
            DossierIdMap.put(j.Dossier_voyage__c, ls);
        } else {
            string[] ls = new string[] {};
            ls.add(j.Id);
            DossierIdMap.put(j.Dossier_voyage__c, ls);
        }
    }

    Map < Id, Id > FactureIdMap = new Map < Id, Id > ();

    List < Facture__c > factureId = [SELECT Id, Dossier_voyage__c FROM Facture__c WHERE Dossier_voyage__c IN: DossierIdMap.keySet() ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];

    for (Facture__c b: factureId) {

        FactureIdMap.put(b.Dossier_voyage__c, b.Id);
    }

    Map < Id, Object[] > FactureMap = new Map < Id, Object[] > ();

    List < Facture__c > facture = [
        SELECT Name, Projet__c, Dossier_voyage__c, Dossier_voyage__r.Opportunite__c, RecordTypeId,
        Taux_acompte__c, Compte__r.Name, Compte__r.BillingStreet, Compte__r.BillingPostalCode,
        Compte__r.BillingCity, Compte__r.BillingCountry, Compte__r.Phone, Compte__r.PersonEmail,
        Numero_de_la_facture__c, Facture_manuelle__c, Dossier_voyage__r.MarqueLogo__c,
        Dossier_voyage__r.Commercial__r.FirstName, Dossier_voyage__r.Name,
        Dossier_voyage__r.Pays_principal__r.Name, Dossier_voyage__r.Date_du_voyage_aller__c,
        Dossier_voyage__r.Date_du_voyage_retour__c, Dossier_voyage__r.Nombre_de_Pax__c,
        Solde_du__c, Reglements_cumules__c, Dossier_voyage__r.N_Cota_contrat__c, Dossier_voyage__r.Technicienne__r.FirstName,
        Dossier_voyage__r.Technicienne__c, Type__c, Total_TTC__c
        FROM Facture__c
        WHERE Id IN: FactureIdMap.keySet()
    ];


    for (Facture__c g: facture) {

        FactureMap.put(g.Id, new Object[] {
            g.Name, g.Projet__c, g.Dossier_voyage__c, g.Dossier_voyage__r.Opportunite__c, g.RecordTypeId,
                g.Taux_acompte__c, g.Compte__r.Name, g.Compte__r.BillingStreet, g.Compte__r.BillingPostalCode,
                g.Compte__r.BillingCity, g.Compte__r.BillingCountry, g.Compte__r.Phone, g.Compte__r.PersonEmail,
                g.Numero_de_la_facture__c, g.Facture_manuelle__c, g.Dossier_voyage__r.MarqueLogo__c,
                g.Dossier_voyage__r.Commercial__r.FirstName, g.Dossier_voyage__r.Name,
                g.Dossier_voyage__r.Pays_principal__r.Name, g.Dossier_voyage__r.Date_du_voyage_aller__c,
                g.Dossier_voyage__r.Date_du_voyage_retour__c, g.Dossier_voyage__r.Nombre_de_Pax__c,
                g.Solde_du__c, g.Reglements_cumules__c, g.Dossier_voyage__r.N_Cota_contrat__c, g.Dossier_voyage__r.Technicienne__r.FirstName
        });
    }




    Reglements = [SELECT Id, Montant__c, Voyageur__c, Dossier__c, Mode_de_paiement__c, Date__c FROM Reglement__c WHERE Dossier__c IN: DossierIdMap.keySet() ORDER BY Date__c];



    Map < Id, Decimal > RegleMap = new Map < Id, Decimal > ();

    for (Reglement__c R: Reglements) {
        if (RegleMap.containsKey(R.Voyageur__c)) {
            RegleMap.put(R.Voyageur__c, RegleMap.get(R.Voyageur__c) + R.Montant__c);
        } else {

            RegleMap.put(R.Voyageur__c, R.Montant__c);
        }




    }
    List < PAX__c > RegleUpdate = new list < PAX__c > ();
    for (PAX__C j: DossierId) {
        if (RegleMap.containsKey(j.Id)) {
            j.R_gl__c = RegleMap.get(j.Id);
            RegleUpdate.add(j);
        }
    }
    update RegleUpdate;


    List < Sous_ligne_de_facture__c > sousLignesDeFactureLieesAuxVoyageurs = [
        SELECT Prix_unitaire_HT__c, Montant_TTC__c,
        Ligne_de_facture__r.Option__r.Titre__c,
        Ligne_de_facture__r.Option__r.Name,
        Ligne_de_facture__r.Libelle__c, Voyageur__c, Voyageur__r.PAX_r_f_rent__c, Voyageur__r.Total_TTC__c, Voyageur__r.Taux_d_acompte__c

        FROM Sous_ligne_de_facture__c
        WHERE Ligne_de_facture__r.Facture__c =: factureId
        AND Ligne_de_facture__r.Facture__r.Dossier_voyage__c IN: DossierIdMap.keySet()
        ORDER BY Ligne_de_facture__r.Option__c
    ];

    Map < Id, Sous_ligne_de_facture__c[] > slfMap = new Map < Id, Sous_ligne_de_facture__c[] > ();

    for (Sous_ligne_de_facture__c slf: sousLignesDeFactureLieesAuxVoyageurs) {

        if (slfMap.containsKey(slf.Voyageur__c)) {
            List < Sous_ligne_de_facture__c > ls = new list < Sous_ligne_de_facture__c > ();
            ls = slfMap.get(slf.Voyageur__c);
            ls.add(slf);

            slfMap.put(slf.Voyageur__c, ls);
        } else if (slfMap.containsKey(slf.Voyageur__r.PAX_r_f_rent__c)) {
            List < Sous_ligne_de_facture__c > ls = new list < Sous_ligne_de_facture__c > ();
            ls = slfMap.get(slf.Voyageur__r.PAX_r_f_rent__c);
            ls.add(slf);
            slfMap.put(slf.Voyageur__r.PAX_r_f_rent__c, ls);
        } else {
            List < Sous_ligne_de_facture__c > ls = new list < Sous_ligne_de_facture__c > ();
            ls.add(slf);
            slfMap.put(slf.Voyageur__c, ls);
        }

    }


    for (List < Sous_ligne_de_facture__c > key: slfMap.values()) {
        for (Sous_ligne_de_facture__c slf: key) {
            if (slf.Ligne_de_facture__r.Libelle__c == 'FORFAIT') {
                sousLignesDeFactureDuForfait.add(slf);
            } else if (slf.Ligne_de_facture__r.Option__c != null) {
                sousLignesDeFactureDesOptions.add(slf);
            }
        }

        if (!sousLignesDeFactureDuForfait.isEmpty()) {
            totalTTC += sousLignesDeFactureDuForfait[0].Prix_unitaire_HT__c * sousLignesDeFactureDuForfait.size();
            ForfaitPU_HT = sousLignesDeFactureDuForfait[0].Prix_unitaire_HT__c;
            nbParticipantsForfait = sousLignesDeFactureDuForfait.size();

        }
        if (!sousLignesDeFactureDesOptions.isEmpty()) {
            for (Sous_ligne_de_facture__c slfo: sousLignesDeFactureDesOptions) {
                totalTTC += slfo.Prix_unitaire_HT__c * 100 / slfo.Voyageur__r.Taux_d_acompte__c;
                
                if (LignesDeFactureDesOptions.containskey(slfo.Ligne_de_facture__r.Option__r.Name)) {
                    LignesDeFactureDesOptions.get(slfo.Ligne_de_facture__r.Option__r.Name).Montant_TTC__c = LignesDeFactureDesOptions.get(slfo.Ligne_de_facture__r.Option__r.Name).Montant_TTC__c + slfo.Prix_unitaire_HT__c * 100 /slfo.Voyageur__r.Taux_d_acompte__c;
                    LignesDeFactureDesOptions.get(slfo.Ligne_de_facture__r.Option__r.Name).Quantite__c = LignesDeFactureDesOptions.get(slfo.Ligne_de_facture__r.Option__r.Name).Quantite__c + 1;
                } else {
                    Ligne_de_facture__c LF = new Ligne_de_facture__c();
                   
                    LF.Montant_TTC__c = slfo.Prix_unitaire_HT__c * 100 / slfo.Voyageur__r.Taux_d_acompte__c;
                    LF.Quantite__c = 1;
                    LF.Prix_de_l_option__c = slfo.Prix_unitaire_HT__c * 100 / slfo.Voyageur__r.Taux_d_acompte__c;
                    LignesDeFactureDesOptions.put(slfo.Ligne_de_facture__r.Option__r.Name, LF);
                }
            }
        }
        List < PAX__c > spUpdate = new list < PAX__c > ();
        for (Sous_ligne_de_facture__c slf: key) {

            for (PAX__C j: scope) {
                if (j.id == slf.Voyageur__c && slf.Voyageur__r.PAX_r_f_rent__c== null) {
                    j.Total_TTC__c = totalTTC;
                    spUpdate.add(j);
                }
            }


        }
        update spUpdate;


    }




}
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    System.debug('Shazam!');

}
```

}

Do you know what causes the problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: The syntax `SELECT Id FROM PAX__C WHERE LIMIT 1` is wrong. You should only include `WHERE` if you have a condition expression. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm).

Comment: Oh, sorry, made this mistake when I wrote the question,
corrected it (but the problem still remain)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Having a code dump like this isn't very helpful. Additionally, it is important you include exact wording of the error message; "Too much soql querys" is your own wording. This makes sure the community understands exactly what's going wrong and also makes the Q&A more searchable. Additionally, incorrectly indented code makes your code dump very hard to interpret.

Comment: I just got my IDE to reformat and tidy the code to make it easier to read.

Comment: The fundamental issue is that you have not bulkified your code and you have a sequence of queries for voyageurId, DossierId, factureId, facture, voyageursMap, Ps, Reglements, sousLignesDeFactureLieesAuxVoyageursV and sousLignesDeFactureLieesAuxVoyageurs within the loop over PAX__c records in the scope. Salesforce allows up to 100 SOQL queries in each transaction. Do a search for "salesforce bulkification" to find articles that will help you understand how to avoid these sorts of issues.

Comment: You could also review [Apex Design Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/apex_code_best_practices).

Comment: So I can't put any SOQL queries ( at least not as much) within the loop. Does that mean that I need to create a list/map outside of the loop for each queries you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, that's basically right. Without understanding the purpose of the code (and I don't read French which doesn't help) I can't give you more advice. Feel free to [edit] the question to explain in detail what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: NB: You should avoid putting any queries in a loop. With batches, scope size defaults to 200 and since you only have 100 SOQL queries per transaction you'll always have the chance to fail with a too many queries error in a bulk scenario. Yes, there's a workaround to set a smaller scope size, but that's fudging it rather than fixing it.

Comment: I've tried to change them into map that get the ID and the PAX__C (equivalent of the account), but i dont get how i should refer them in other queries that i need to change into maps... Any ideas/hints? (i'm sorry, i'm new at this)

Comment: For instances, if my voyageurId is a MAP, how do i refer to it in queries like " WHERE Id = :voyageurId "? Do you have any ressource or link that i can study to answer this question ?

Comment: Take a look at some of the scenarios in [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) which may help you with this.

Comment: I think that i've managed to bulkify my work, but in the end of the code, line 220, on the update SpUpdate, I get a " dupplicate Id" error, do you know what is causing it?

Comment: The problem is caused by having two entries in the same list with the same Id value during a DML update. Can you clarify which update in your code causes the issue? Sometimes you need to use Set instead of List to ensure you have unique IDs, for example.