# Apex issue in production Too Many SQL queries

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I created a LWC using an APEX class
Everything worked perfectly on Sandbox but when I moved my code to production I get  Too Many SQL queries 101

I don't know what to .. is there something wrong with my code ?

```
public class ApprovalTable {
    public ApprovalTable(){
        
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<wrapperClass> getWrapperClassList() {
       List<wrapperClass> wrapperList = new List<wrapperClass>();
       for(Opportunity Opp: [SELECT Name, id, StageName, Region__c, Country__c, Owner.LastName, Owner.FirstName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN(SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Approval__c WHERE (Type__c = 'Investment_Committee' or Type__c = 'Pre_IC') AND Status__c != Null)]){
           
           wrapperClass wc = new wrapperClass();
           AggregateResult[] IC_max_date_data = [SELECT Opportunity__c, max(date__c) maxDate 
                                                  FROM Approval__c WHERE Opportunity__r.Id = :Opp.Id 
                                                  AND Type__c = 'Investment_Committee' 
                                                  AND date__c != Null 
                                                  GROUP BY Opportunity__c];
           system.debug('IC_max_date_data');
           system.debug(IC_max_date_data);
           
           AggregateResult[] Pre_IC_max_date_data = [SELECT Opportunity__c, max(date__c) maxPreIcDate 
                                                  FROM Approval__c WHERE Opportunity__r.Id = :Opp.Id 
                                                  AND Type__c = 'Pre_IC' 
                                                  AND date__c != Null 
                                                  GROUP BY Opportunity__c];
           system.debug('Pre_IC_max_date_data');
           system.debug(Pre_IC_max_date_data);
              
           if (IC_max_date_data.isEmpty()){                    
               wc.icDate = Null;
               wc.icStatus = Null;
           } else {
               system.debug('test');
               Date max_date = (Date)IC_max_date_data[0].get('maxDate');
               system.debug(max_date);
               List<Approval__c> IC_Approval_data = [SELECT Date__c, Status__c, Type__c 
                                                    FROM Approval__c
                                                    WHERE Opportunity__r.Id = :Opp.Id
                                                    AND Type__c = 'Investment_Committee'
                                                    AND date__c = :max_date                                                 
                                                    ];
               wc.icDate = IC_Approval_data[0].Date__c;
               wc.icStatus = IC_Approval_data[0].Status__c;         
           }
           
           if (Pre_IC_max_date_data.isEmpty()){                    
               wc.PreicDate = Null;
               wc.PreicStatus = Null;
           } else {
               Date Pre_max_date = (Date)Pre_IC_max_date_data[0].get('maxPreIcDate');
               List<Approval__c> Pre_IC_Approval_data = [SELECT Date__c, Status__c, Type__c 
                                                    FROM Approval__c
                                                    WHERE Opportunity__r.Id = :Opp.Id
                                                    AND Type__c = 'Pre_IC'
                                                    AND date__c = :Pre_max_date                                                 
                                                    ];
               wc.PreicDate = Pre_IC_Approval_data[0].Date__c;
               wc.PreicStatus = Pre_IC_Approval_data[0].Status__c;         
           }
           
           
           wc.OppName = Opp.name;
           wc.OppStage = Opp.StageName;
           wc.OppOwner = Opp.Owner.LastName;
           wc.OppRegion = Opp.Region__c;
           wc.OppCountry = Opp.Country__c;
           wc.OppFirstOwner = Opp.Owner.FirstName;
           wrapperList.add(wc);
           
       
       }
       system.debug(wrapperList); 
       return wrapperList;
       
   }
    
   public class wrapperClass{
       @AuraEnabled public String OppName;
       @AuraEnabled public String OppStage;
       @auraEnabled public date icDate;
       @auraEnabled public String icStatus;
       @auraEnabled public date PreicDate;
       @auraEnabled public String PreicStatus;
       @auraEnabled public String OppOwner;
       @auraEnabled public String OppFirstOwner;
       @auraEnabled public String OppRegion;
       @auraEnabled public String OppCountry;
   }    
}
```

Comment: Querying data in loops is a really really bad idea.

Comment: What should I do then ? how should I achieve what I am looking for ?

Comment: This looks pretty similar to a common question, please check this answer at [How do I bulkify queries for directly or indirectly related records?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records)

Comment: The reason you are getting TMSQL error is because the data in production is different than in sandbox. So your loops are probably more than ~35, which when you muitply by 3 queries in your loop, it errors out. Query all records in maps outside the loop and reference them inside. Use the link shared my Jeferson Chaves above to understand more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try 2 things:

1. Send all opportunities into the opportunity query like below and since its grouped by opportunity it will give you `IC_max_date_data,Pre_IC_max_date_data` by opportunity. `WHERE Opportunity__r.Id IN :Opp.Id`
2. If 1 doesn't work then extract the approval data for all opportunity and do the aggregation yourself within the loop.

Comment: I am not sure I understood number 1 option ..

Comment: I think I understand .. let me try

Answer (score 0):

You are using SOQL queries inside For loops, so if the first loop returns more than 100 records, then you are running the query for more than 100 times in one loop. This is exceeding the governor limit.
What you can do is fetch the Opportunity IDs from the first Select Query and then you can run the query outside the loop and then perfom the tasks.

Best Regards,
Aastha