# Help Needed to Bulkify Scheduled Apex Class PLEASE

Tags: apex, soql, scheduled-apex, governorlimits

Hello awesome Developers,

I have the following scheduled apex class that I plan on running nightly or possibly a few times a day.  The purpose of this scheduled class is to replace the standard Campaign Influence and Attribution that comes out of the box with Salesforce.  It was too restrictive for us to utilize and we would like to try our own route before needing to purchase another 3rd party piece of software.

So the class is getting all opportunities with some filters from the system, looping through those opportunities to find all campaign members where the contact on the member record's accountId matches the opportunities Account ID being looped on as well as that the campaign start date was within the last 90 days before the opportunity was closed won.

Then I am using that info from what I found above to add a new record to a custom object to create the attribution values with values from that campaign member record and the opp record.  I am hitting the dreaded "Too Many SOQL Queries" error, and I have been banging my head against a wall trying to figure out to bulkify the code below.  Can you be my hero and help me out with some instructions and maybe an example to follow?  Appreciate any help you all can provide me :)

Class Code:

```java
global class CampaignAttributionScheduledClass Implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        runClass();        
    }
    
    public void runClass(){
        
        //Grab filtered Opportunities from the system
        List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>([SELECT ID, Name, CloseDate, AccountId, Type, Department__c 
                                                        FROM Opportunity WHERE Department__c = 'MDR' AND StageName = 'Closed Won' AND Type = 'New Business']);
        //Declare a MAP of Opps in above list to create keypair values for comparison work
        Map<Id, Opportunity> oMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(opps);
        //Map to hold paired records from For Loops below
        List<Opportunity_Attribution__c> attRecordsToUpsert = new List<Opportunity_Attribution__c>();
        
        //Null Check
        if(oMap.size()>0){
        //Start looping through the opps found in the MAP
        for(Id oppKey : oMap.keySet()){
            //Create localized Opportunity to use fields
            Opportunity loopedOpp = oMap.get(oppKey);
            //Grab all Campaign Members in the system for this Opp in the loop from Campaigns within 90 days of opp close
            List<CampaignMember> camps = new List<CampaignMember>([SELECT ID, Campaign_Name__c, Campaign.StartDate, 
                                                               ContactId, Contact.AccountId, CampaignId FROM CampaignMember 
                                                               WHERE Contact.AccountId = :loopedOpp.AccountId AND 
                                                               Campaign.StartDate >= :loopedOpp.CloseDate-90 AND Campaign.StartDate <= :loopedOpp.CloseDate]);
            //Loop through the campaign members found to create attribution record for each member/campaign
            for(CampaignMember rm : camps){
                //Create Attribution Record
                Opportunity_Attribution__c loopedAtt = new Opportunity_Attribution__c();
                    loopedAtt.Campaign_ID__c = rm.CampaignId;
                    loopedAtt.Member_ID__c = rm.ContactId;
                    loopedAtt.Name = rm.CampaignId + '-' + loopedOpp.Id + '-' + rm.ContactId;
                    loopedAtt.Opportunity__c = loopedOpp.Id;
                    loopedAtt.Unique_Name__c = rm.CampaignId + '-' + loopedOpp.Id + '-' + rm.ContactId;
                //Add New Opp Attribution Record To System
                attRecordsToUpsert.add(loopedAtt);
            }
        }
    }
        //Null Check before upsert
        if(attRecordsToUpsert.size()>0){
            upsert attRecordsToUpsert;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I bulkify queries for directly or indirectly related records?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records)

Comment: Have you also checked the [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk)?

Comment: The third scenario in that canonical QA _partially_ applies to this question, but also partially does not, as this scenario doesn't (unless someone sees a clever way I'm missing) allow for the use of a composite key.

Comment: @DavidReed There's a very tricky way to get a composite key to work with overriding equals and hashCode, but that's really an advanced topic I'd rather avoid unless needed as a last resort.

Comment: Oh, that's brilliant; never would've thought of (mis?)using object equality that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're struggling because you can't *directly* bulkify this query

```
List<CampaignMember> camps = new List<CampaignMember>(
    [
        SELECT ID, Campaign_Name__c, Campaign.StartDate, 
                   ContactId, Contact.AccountId, CampaignId
        FROM CampaignMember 
        WHERE Contact.AccountId = :loopedOpp.AccountId 
              AND Campaign.StartDate >= :loopedOpp.CloseDate-90 
              AND Campaign.StartDate <= :loopedOpp.CloseDate
    ]
);
```

because the filters for `CampaignMember` vary based on which `Opportunity` it's taken in context of.

You can do two things:

1. You can aggregate all of the dates for the Opportunities (find the earliest and the latest, that is) and "over-query": query all Campaign Members with any Opportunity's `AccountId`, and whose Campaign dates fall within the *broadest total range of dates across all Opportunities*. Then, you can digest those `CampaignMember` records into a data structure like a `Map<Id, List<CampaignMember>>`, keyed on the `AccountId`, and finally iterate through the relevant `CampaignMember` records in Apex to identify which ones have the right dates for any given Opportunity.

   This strategy certainly works, although the code's a little more complex; it may run into other limits risks, like SOQL rows or even CPU time, depending on your total data volume and what percentage of that data volume is actually responsive to your queries.
2. You can accept that your code is SOQL-inefficient in exchange for being straightforward, and build it as a Schedulable Batch Apex class instead of a Scheduled Apex class. Your batch class can run at the right batch size to allow you to stay under the SOQL query limit for each invocation of `execute()`.

Comment: I had a feeling you were writing something, lol. But my answer is, I suppose, just different enough to have been worth salvaging.

Comment: +1 from me, good example!

Comment: Thank you for your help!  That gave me what I needed in order to tackle this need.  Thanks again, you all are rockstars!

Answer (score 3):

You have to make the inner loop query into something that's accessible all at once. You can't bulkify that query directly, as you would need to have multiple date offsets. Fortunately, you just need to find the minimum and maximum dates, and then query those. You'll have an extra if statement in the middle to select only the appropriate records, which is an unfortunate side effect, but that's how it has to be.

I wrote about the design in this answer in my blog post [The Aggregate-Query-Update Pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html). You'll end up using this a lot, so it's worth learning about this pattern.

```
global class CampaignAttributionScheduledClass Implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        runClass();        
    }
    
    public void runClass(){
        
        //Grab filtered Opportunities from the system
        List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT ID, Name, CloseDate, AccountId, Type, Department__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Department__c = 'MDR' AND StageName = 'Closed Won' AND Type = 'New Business'];
        //Declare a MAP of Opps in above list to create keypair values for comparison work
        List<Opportunity_Attribution__c> attRecordsToUpsert = new List<Opportunity_Attribution__c>();
        Date minDate, maxDate;
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id, List<CampaignMember>> membersByAccount = new Map<Id, List<CampaignMember>>();
        for(Opportunity loopedOpp: opps) {
            // Special trick: boolean comparison to null returns false, so this statement works with null values.
            // So to null-check against min date, we invert check (greater than), and then NOT the result
            if(!(loopedOpp.CloseDate > minDate)) {
                minDate = loopedOpp.CloseDate;
            }
            if(!(loopedOpp.CloseDate < maxDate)) {
                maxDate = loopedUp.CloseDate;
            }
            accountIds.add(loopedOpp.AccountId);
            membersByAccount.put(loopedOpp.AccountId, new List<CampaignMember>());
        }
        
        for(CampaignMember record: [SELECT ID, Campaign_Name__c, Campaign.StartDate, 
                                            ContactId, Contact.AccountId, CampaignId 
                                        FROM CampaignMember 
                                        WHERE Contact.AccountId = :accountIds AND 
                                                Campaign.StartDate >= :minDate-90 AND Campaign.StartDate <= :maxDate]) {
            membersByAccount.get(record.Contact.AccountId).add(record);
        }
        for(Opportunity loopedOpp: opps) {
            CampaignMember[] camps = membersByAccount.get(loopedOpp.AccountId);
            minDate = loopedOpp.CloseDate.addDays(-90);
            maxDate = loopedOpp.CloseDate;
            for(CampaignMember rm : camps){
                //Create Attribution Record
                if(rm.Campaign.StartDate >= minDate && rm.Campaign.StartDate <= maxDate) {
                    Opportunity_Attribution__c loopedAtt = new Opportunity_Attribution__c();
                        loopedAtt.Campaign_ID__c = rm.CampaignId;
                        loopedAtt.Member_ID__c = rm.ContactId;
                        loopedAtt.Name = rm.CampaignId + '-' + loopedOpp.Id + '-' + rm.ContactId;
                        loopedAtt.Opportunity__c = loopedOpp.Id;
                        loopedAtt.Unique_Name__c = rm.CampaignId + '-' + loopedOpp.Id + '-' + rm.ContactId;
                    //Add New Opp Attribution Record To System
                    attRecordsToUpsert.add(loopedAtt);
                }
            }
        }
        upsert attRecordsToUpsert;
    }
}
```

Miscellaneous notes:

An empty list is not a null list. You don't need to `if(!somelist.isEmpty())` or variants in most cases, because it is acceptable to iterate over an empty list. Same with the DML statement at the end. No need to see if the list isn't empty yet.

A query result is always a list. You don't need to `new List<someType>([inline query]);`, that's just rather confusing logic.

You may need to break this out into a batchable/queueable if you expect more than 50,000 rows to be returned from the campaign member query. That isn't included in this answer.