# Query in Batch Apex returns "List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, static-resources, test-setup

I have test class where I am using a csv file to insert 200 records Account data.
First 100 are like:
[image]

remaining 100 are like:

[image]

I am using above created test class to test a batch apex class which has below logic in start and execute methods:

```
global  Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {                  
        return Database.getQuerylocator([SELECT Id, FinServ__SourceSystemId__c, Merged_With__c FROM Account WHERE Merged_With__c <> NULL]); 
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> Accts ) {
        
        for(Account acct : Accts) { 
            Account Acct2 = [SELECT Id, FinServ__SourceSystemId__c FROM Account WHERE Id =: acct.Merged_With__c];
            Database.MergeResult results = Database.merge(Acct2, acct, false);
            if (results.isSuccess()) {
                recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
            } else {
                results.getErrors();
            }   
        }
    }
```

Unit test:

```
@isTest
public class TestCSV {
    
    @testSetup
    public static void testSetup(){
        List<SObject> lstWacc = Test.loadData(Account.sObjectType,'TestWinningAccountCreation');
        List<SObject> lstAcc = Test.loadData(Account.sObjectType,'TestAccountCreation');
    }
    
    static testmethod void staticResourceLoad(){
        List<Account> loosingAcc = [SELECT Id, Merged_With__c, Merged_With_Source_System_Id__c FROM Account WHERE FinServ__SourceSystemId__c LIKE 'sourcesysid00%'];
        List<Account> winningAcc = [SELECT Id, Merged_With__c, Merged_With_Source_System_Id__c, FinServ__SourceSystemId__c FROM Account WHERE FinServ__SourceSystemId__c LIKE 'wsourcesysid00%'];
        
        System.assertEquals(loosingAcc.size(), 100);
        System.assertEquals(winningAcc.size(), 100);
        
        Test.startTest();
        AccountsMergeBatch myAccountsMergeBatch = new AccountsMergeBatch(); 
        AccountsMergeBatch.start(0);
        Test.stopTest();
        
        
    }  
}
```

**Problem**:
query in the execute method is throwing this error "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject" even though Merged_With__c value is there.

can anyone identify what could be the problem here?

Comment: This is a well documented problem. Please just Google it. More than that, you really should avoid queries in loops as this is an anti-pattern and will lead to governor limits issues depending how many iterations the loop performs in a given transaction.

Comment: We need to see your unit test, too, in order for us to help you.

Comment: @PhilW - I tried finding other ways to avoid using soql inside the loop but wasn't able to find a way.

Comment: @sfdcfox Just added unit test class as well.

Comment: I don't see where you're calling the execute method. You should use `Database.executeBatch(new AccountsMergeBatch());`

Comment: @sfdcfox there was another start method in the batch class which was calling Database.executeBatch but I removed it as it was unnecessary. Please ignore this statement AccountsMergeBatch.start(0); from test class.

Comment: Take a look at [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) for details about different bulkification tactics.

Comment: You are querying the accounts based on:
Account WHERE Merged_With__c <> NULL

Is it possible that there are accounts with a non-null value in the merged_with__c field, but that value doesn't correspond to another accounts id? If so, that would probably explain why the second query isn't returning an account.

Comment: @eaeaoo there are 100 Accounts without Merged_with__c value and another 100 Accounts with Merged_with__c field populated with Account Ids of first created Accounts. No other value on the field Merged_with__c