# Trigger for New and Existing Account Cases without using query in For-Loop

Tags: apex, soql

Good day,

I am writing a code that would check if an active case is existing or not.
An `if statement` would figure out whether the case status is New || Working || Escalated.
Then, a `switch statement` would determine what type of account this client have (I have created a field under `Account sObject` named `client_type_c`)

I created a `trigger` on Case to prevent users from exceeding cases. And will show error messages on object level.

Comment: welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. This site isn't about implementing your requirements for you, but rather helping you with specific issues you've run into from the work you've done. If you have an idea of what to do, I'd recommend you attempt it and then [edit] your question with the actual code from that attempt (not an image of the code) and any specific issues/things that are not working as you intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how [switch statements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_switch.htm) work in Apex. You can only use static values to determine which branch to take.

That would look like:

```
switch on newCase.Status {
  when 'New','Working','Escalated' {
    // Do something here
  }
}
```

Further, it looks like you're trying to check the Client Type of the case's account? That means you're going to need to query the accounts, and then check the results of the query.

Comment: Yes, @sfdcfox. But I was advised to not to use a query inside a for-loop, which makes it hard.

Comment: @Archangel08 See [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/321847/2984) for ways to bulkify your queries.