# Need help moving SOQL out of the loop

Tags: apex, trigger, query, loop, bulkification

*Hello, I need move this query out of loop:*

`List<Lead> dupeLeads = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Lead WHERE Id != :Ld.Id AND Email  =: Ld.Email];`

*I'm testing various guides on "bulkifying ", but I can't get it to work. Thanks in advance*

*The code it is:*

```
trigger FindDupeLead on Lead(before Insert, before Update, after UnDelete){
    
    if(Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate || Trigger.IsUnDelete){
        
        for(Lead Ld : Trigger.New){
            if(Ld.Email != null){
                Ld.Duplicate_Lead_Links__c = '';    
                List<Lead> dupeLeads = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Lead WHERE Id != :Ld.Id AND Email  =: Ld.Email];
                
                if(dupeLeads.size() > 0){
                    for(Lead EveryLead : dupeLeads){
                        Ld.Duplicate_Lead_Links__c += 'https://komainu89-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Lead/' + everyLead.Id + '/view' + '\n';
                    }
                }
            }
            if(Ld.Email == null){
                Ld.Duplicate_Lead_Links__c = ''; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason to no use a [standard duplicate rule](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_standard_lead_rule.htm&type=5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Gather leads' emails in Trigger.
2. Query all leads with these emails.
3. Store them in map which connects lead email with leads' ids.
4. Run through your leads from Trigger once more: get stored leads ids related to current lead email, set duplicate links (check if current lead id does not equal to duplicate lead id).

```
Set<String> emails = new Set<String>();
for (Lead lead : Trigger.new) {
    emails.add(lead.Email);
}

Map<String, List<Id>> emailToLeadsIds = new Map<String, List<Id>>();
for (Lead lead : [SELECT Id, Email FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :emails]) {
    if (!emailToLeadsIds.containsKey(lead.Email)) {
        emailToLeadsIds.put(lead.Email, new List<Id>());
    }
    
    emailToLeadsIds.get(lead.Email).add(lead.Id);
}

for (Lead lead : Trigger.new) {
    if (lead.Duplicate_Lead_Links__c == null) {
        lead.Duplicate_Lead_Links__c = '';
    }
    if (emailToLeadsIds.containsKey(lead.Email)) {
        for (Id duplicateLeadId : emailToLeadsIds.get(lead.Email)) {
            if (duplicateLeadId != lead.Id) {
                lead.Duplicate_Lead_Links__c += 'https://komainu89-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Lead/' + duplicateLeadId + '/view' + '\n';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works perfectly, but in the field 'Duplicate_Lead_Links__c', it appears 'null' before the URL, it is not a serious problem, but would you know why that happens?

Comment: Yes, sure, it's because you need to initialize `lead.Duplicate_Lead_Links__c = ''` before for-loop on `duplicateLeadId`. That happens because if you don't do it, it's adding links to the null value, and basic implementation of toString() for null is 'null' and not an empty string.

Comment: I have added new code line to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't read through it already [How do I bulkify queries for directly or indirectly related records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) is a good place to start.

The general idea is that you need to first gather the data that you're going to use in the `WHERE` clause of your query (using a loop) and *then* perform your query (outside of all loops). You can then iterate over the results.

Things aren't quite that simple when you have multiple filters that you're feeding data into. No matter what you try to do, if you have more than one filter, trying to aggregate data before the query will result in the filters returning the cartesian product of results.

There are two main ways to deal with this

1. Add a formula field which combines your two target fields (which allows you to reduce your `WHERE` clause to a single filter)
2. Choose to do some processing/filtering in Apex to allow you to reduce your `WHERE` clause to a single filter

Using a formula field here doesn't really strike me as the correct approach (because your first filter uses `!=` and your second filter uses `=`). So I'd take the second approach.

Instead of trying to filter out duplicates with the same Id in the query, just focus on getting all of the duplicates. We can weed out ones with the same Id later, in Apex (which we can make easier by carefully choosing how we store those duplicates).

```
// First, focus on getting the emails we need to check
// This is the 'Aggregate' step
Set<String> givenEmails = new Set<String>();
for(Lead l :Trigger.new){
    givenEmails.add(l.Email);
}

// You could perform a check if the lead email is null inside of the previous loop
//   but I'm more fond of simply removing nulls after the fact
givenEmails.remove(null);

// Now we can perform the main query (outside of all loops)
List<Lead> leadsWithGivenEmails = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :givenEmails];
```

Now we can focus on getting the result you want. Given an email, you want to find all duplicate leads. Once you get that, you want to ignore the lead with the same Id as what you're currently working on. Associating one piece of data to another piece of data is what `Map` is good for. You could get away with a relatively simple `Map<String, List<Lead>>`, where the key of the map is the lead's Email, but if you instead use a `Map<String, Set<Id>>` I think it'll end up making your code more simple.

The key of the Map is still the Lead's Email, but by storing a `Set<Id>` as the map's value, you make it easy (and efficient) to remove the Id of the Lead you're currently working on.

Why not a `List<Lead>` or a `Set<Lead>`?
You could certainly use those, but since you only seem to need the Lead's Id it makes sense to only store the Id. Using the appropriate data structures and doing a little work upfront makes it easier to use later on.

```
Map<String, Set<Id>> emailToLeadIds = new Map<String, Set<Id>>();
for(Lead l :leadsWithGivenEmails){
    // This is a pretty standard pattern for populating maps
    // Check to see if the key exists in the map
    if(!emailToLeadIds.containsKey(l.Email)){
        // Put the key (and an initial value) into the map if the key doesn't
        //   exist yet
        emailToLeadIds.put(l.Email, new Set<Id>());
    }

    // Now we can use .get() without needing to worry about doing any null checks
    emailToLeadIds.get(l.Email).add(l.Id);
}

// Now you can loop over trigger.new one more time and perform the main processing
//   that you want to do
for(Lead l :trigger.new){
    if(String.isBlank(l.Email)){
        l.Duplicate_Lead_Links__c = '';
        // Using 'continue' here means we skip the rest of the loop
        //   and start processing the next record
        // Allows us to write the rest of the code for the loop without
        //   needing to wrap it in an 'else' block
        continue;
    }

    // Cloning the resulting set helps avoid an issue where the set of Ids
    //   would be incomplete if you had 2 leads with the same Email in
    //   trigger.new
    Set<Id> leadIdsWithSameEmail = emailToLeadIds.get(l.Email).clone();
    leadIdsWithSameEmail.remove(l.Id);

    // There is a way to avoid this explicit loop using String.join(), but
    //   I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader
    for(Id leadId :leadIdsWithSameEmail){
        l.Duplicate_Lead_Links__c += 'the start of your url' + leadId + '/view\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: `leadIdsWithSameEmail.remove(l.Id);` You should not do that in loop, because in trigger might be leads with same email and for the second lead the one you have removed won't appear in duplicate results. Better make an if-condition.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova Right, that slipped my mind. We can still use the Set approach though. That issue can easily be fixed by cloning the set (which I'll edit my answer to reflect).

Comment: Sure, but I don't think that will make any difference in time complexity comparing to if-clause approach. However, I should agree, looks more informatively.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova Yep, I think the time complexity is the same. This general style is mostly a personal preference. As I've continued to code, I've begun to see the appeal of trying to keep the amount of nested blocks to a minimum (i.e. keeping the code as un-indented as practical). I think fewer nested blocks is easier to read and reason about. That, and I like using Sets and Maps to avoid (explicit) loops and if-else if chains.

Comment: @DerekF Regarding that last point, ApexPMD agrees with you. Less is more.