# ERROR: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, insert

```
trigger exerciseSIX on Account (before insert){ 
    List<Account> allAcc=[SELECT BillingPostalCode FROM Account];
                               
    System.debug(allAcc.size());
    
    List<Account> newAcct=new List<Account>();
    for(Account a: trigger.new){
         newAcct.add(a);
    }
    
    for (Account b: newAcct)  {
           for(Account c: allAcc){
               if(b.BillingPostalCode.substring(0,2) == c.BillingPostalCode.substring(0,2)){
                  b.Website=c.Website;    
                } 
               else{
                   b.Website='www.technologies.com';
               }
        }
    }  
        
        
}
```

I am trying to compare the BillingPostalCode of newly added account with the BillingPostalCode of the all old accounts.

If there is any existing accounts already have a BillingPostalCode that starts with the same 2 digits, I will copy the website (standard field) of that account onto the new account that is being inserted or updated. If not, I will set website = "www.technologies.com". but it is giving NULLPointerException on line `for(Account c: allAcc)`

Comment: I think you're mistaken about the position of the `NullPointerException` - it's on the following line, the `if`. What does that tell you?

Comment: Also note that this code is _extremely_ inefficient and will fail at any significant data volume. The pattern in [the "I need data from indirectly related records based on one or more input record fields" section](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) of our canonical QA is applicable here, although your situation is actually rather simpler. You need to query for only Accounts that actually match one of the zip codes in your trigger set.

Comment: @DavidReed hmmm okay thanks mate

Comment: Given the name of the trigger, this seems like it might be a trailhead challenge or an interview question. If that's the case, then helping you would defeat the purpose of the exercise (which is to measure what knowledge you yourself have). I also agree with David's assessment on where the error is (it cannot be on the `for()` line that you indicated, that is physically impossible). The resource that David pointed you to contains good information, and you should study it so you can improve this trigger.

Comment: Thank you guys @DerekF . i getting somewhere by using the resource David pointed. (no it's not trailhead or interview question) I just found some exercises on internet.