# Create a Unique Map from another Complex map structure in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, map, collection

I have a method like the below

```
 public static  void formatInput()
{
    Map<string,List<string>> parentMap=new Map<string,List<string>>();
    Map<string,List<string>> uniqueMap=new Map<string,List<string>>();
    parentMap.put('2#3',new List<string>{'Red','Purple'});
    parentMap.put('1#3',new List<string>{'Green'});
    parentMap.put('1#2',new List<string>{'Yellow'});
    parentMap.put('1#2#3',new List<string>{'Blue'});
    for(string combineCat:parentMap.KeySet()){
        for(string indCat:combineCat.split('#'))
        {
            if(!uniqueMap.containsKey(indCat))
            {
                List<string> primaryLst=parentMap.get(combineCat);
                 uniqueMap.put(indCat,primaryLst);
            }
               
            else
                uniqueMap.get(indCat).addAll(parentMap.get(combineCat));
            
        }
    }
    system.debug('uniqueMap :'+uniqueMap);
    
}
```

I am intending to get an output map like

> {1=(Green, Yellow, Blue), 2=(Red, Purple, Yellow, Blue), 3=(Red,
> Purple, Green, Blue)}

.

But the above code return like below

```
uniqueMap :{1=(Green, Yellow, Blue), 2=(Red, Purple, Green, Yellow, Blue, Blue), 3=(already output)}
```

Could you please help me identifying what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that's tripping you up here is that collections store non-primitive types *by reference*, and you're not breaking that reference. That's causing data for your 'unique' lists to inadvertently be shared with one another.

In your code, when you wrote

```
List<string> primaryLst = parentMap.get(combineCat);
uniqueMap.put(indCat, primaryLst);
```

The `primaryLst` you're adding to `uniqueMap` is a reference to the same `List<String>` instance that's stored in `parentMap`.

A rough equivalent to what you're ending up doing here is

```java
List<String> twoAndThree = new List<string>{'Red','Purple'};
List<String> oneAndThree = new List<string>{'Green'};

List<String> two = twoAndThree;
List<String> three = twoAndThree;

// Skipping the handling of creating the list for 'one'
three.addAll(oneAndThree);
```

Since `two` and `three` are both references to the same list (`twoAndThree`), when we `three.addAll(oneAndThree);`, you're adding that data to `twoAndThree` and it's reflected in the `two` list as well. That's how you're getting 'Green' (and eventually the extra 'Blue') into your `two` list.

To fix this, you need to break the reference to the original list by either calling `clone()` or creating an entirely new list.

The pattern I use for populating maps like this generally opts to make a new list.

```
for(String key :someKeyCollection){
    // The only thing we concern ourselves with at first is ensuring that
    //   there is a value in the map for the given key (so we don't have to worry
    //   about possibly encountering nulls)
    if(!myMap.containsKey(key)){
        myMap.put(key, new List<String>());
    }

    // Now that we've guaranteed that there's something in the map, we can use the key
    //   freely.
    // This also allows us to avoid needing an 'else' block.
    // Since the list is stored by reference in your map, we can call .addAll() directly
    //   on the result of .get(key)
    myMap.get(key).addAll(otherMap.get(key));
```

Also, your given example should be fine with a `Map<String, List<String>>`, but I'd consider using a `Map<String, Set<String>>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your `if` statement.  If `uniqueMap` does not contain the index, you do this:

```
List<String> primaryLst = parentMap.get(combineCat);
uniqueMap.put(indCat, primaryLst);
```

In Apex, all non-primitive data types (including Arrays) are reference types.  You are assigning `primaryLst` a *reference* to the actual list stored in the `parentMap`, not a copy of that list.  So when `2#3` is processed, a reference to the list `{'Red', 'Purple'}` is being assigned to both `2` and `3`, and if anything else is added to 2, it will appear in 3, and vice-versa.  This is why you see `3=(already output)`... `already output` means that the debug output already includes the *exact* object in question (the list, in this case).

Here's a modified version of your code that produces the correct output.  It always adds a new List to the map, and then adds values to that list.  This avoids storing a reference to an existing list.

```
Map<String,List<String>> parentMap=new Map<String,List<String>>();
Map<String,List<String>> uniqueMap=new Map<String,List<String>>();

parentMap.put('2#3',new List<String>{'Red','Purple'});
parentMap.put('1#3',new List<String>{'Green'});
parentMap.put('1#2',new List<String>{'Yellow'});
parentMap.put('1#2#3',new List<String>{'Blue'});

for (String combineCat : parentMap.KeySet()) {
    for (String indCat : combineCat.split('#')) {
        if (uniqueMap.containsKey(indCat) == false) {
            uniqueMap.put(indCat, new List<String>());
        }
        uniqueMap.get(indCat).addAll(parentMap.get(combineCat));
    }
}

System.debug('uniqueMap :'+uniqueMap);
```

Comment: `uniqueMap.containsKey(indCat) == false` is a bit weird to see. Any reason you didn't just do `!uniqueMap.containsKey(indCat)`?

Comment: @PhilW  When reading code, sometimes my eyes just glide over a `!` without noticing it.  I've just gotten in the habit of not using it, in favor of `== false`.  Especially when scanning code I haven't seen in a while, it's easy (for me at least) to glance at `if (expr)` and miss a leading `!` in the `expr` part.  Consider it defensive coding :D

Comment: If you are missing it while reading, I'd say you're not looking at the detail anyway and it's not important to see (which is fine). If you are missing it while writing, that's a whole other ballgame!

Answer (score 0):

Consider making it a `Map<Object[], Set<String>>` since Sets cannot include duplicate values (adding duplicates is effectively ignored).

I also recommend using an Object array/list as the key since this is much more efficient than using strings built by concatenation. Take a look at the section entitled "I need data from indirectly related records based on one or more input record fields" in the answer for [this previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) for something about this.