# Help in writing trigger in optimised way

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 3 objects , `Account_Associated__c`, `Account` and `OwnerTerritory__c`

Account_Associated__c is a junction object between Account and OwnerTerritory__c with below relationship

**Relationship**

```
Account_Associated__c:                  
    LookUp to Account
    Master-Detail with OwnerTerritory__c (OwnerTerritory__c as Master)
```

**Below are the fields on all 3 objects -**

```
Account:
        OwnerA__c   (Lookup to User)
        OwnerB__c   (Lookup to User)
        OwnerC__c   (Lookup to User)
        OwnerD__c   (Lookup to User)
        Represents_Concern__c (checkbox)

Account_Associated__c:
                    Account__c (lookup to Account)
                    OwnerTerritory__c (Master to OwnerTerritory__c object)
                    POR__c -> Picklist with values (Sales, Global)
                    Brand__c -> Multipicklist with values (A, B, C, D)

OwnerTerritory__c:
                Owner__c (Lookup to User)
```

**Queueable used in trigger**

The below logic is working correctly , only help i need is to write it in a better way using maps.

```
public class AccountOwnerSyncUtility  implements Queueable {
    private Set<String> poResponsibilities;
    private static final String POR_SALES_CONTROL = 'Sales';
    private static final String POR_GLOBAL_ACCOUNT_OWNER = 'Global';
    public set<Id> accId = new  set<Id>();   
    public AccountOwnerSyncUtility(List<Account_Association__c> taaList) {  
        poResponsibilities = new Set<String> {POR_SALES_CONTROL, POR_GLOBAL_ACCOUNT_OWNER};
        for(Account_Association__c taa: taaList) {
            accId.add(taa.Account__c);
        }
    } 
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        Map<Id, Id> terriToOwner = new Map<Id, Id>();
        List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
        List<Account_Association__c> taaListToProcess = [SELECT Id,Account__r.ParentId, Account__r.Represents_Concern__c, IsDeleted, Account__c, Brand__c, POR__c, 
                                                                   OwnerTerritory__c, OwnerTerritory__r.Owner__c
                                                                   FROM Account_Association__c 
                                                                   WHERE Account__c IN: accId AND
                                                                   POR__c IN: poResponsibilities];

        List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id, Parent.OwnerA__c, Parent.OwnerB__c, Parent.OwnerC__c, Parent.OwnerD__c, 
        OwnerA__c, OwnerB__c, OwnerC__c, OwnerD__c,ParentId, Represents_Concern__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN: accId];
        
        for(Account_Association__c t: taaListToProcess) {
            if(t.POR__c == POR_SALES_CONTROL) {
                for(String brand : t.Brand__c.split(';')){
                    terriToOwner.put(t.Id, t.OwnerTerritory__r.Owner__c); 
                } 
            }
            if(t.POR__c == POR_GLOBAL_ACCOUNT_OWNER && t.Account__r.Represents_Concern__c) {
                for(String brand : t.Brand__c.split(';')){
                    terriToOwner.put(t.Id, t.OwnerTerritory__r.Owner__c);  
                } 
            }
        }
            for(Account a : acc) {  
                a.OwnerA__c = null;
                a.OwnerB__c = null;
                a.OwnerC__c = null;
                a.OwnerD__c = null;
                
                a.Parent.OwnerA__c = null;
                a.Parent.OwnerB__c = null;
                a.Parent.OwnerC__c = null;
                a.Parent.OwnerD__c = null;
                for(Account_Association__c taa: taaListToProcess) {  
                    if(a.Id == taa.Account__c) {
                        if(taa.Brand__c.contains('A') && taa.POR__c == POR_GLOBAL_ACCOUNT_OWNER){
                            a.Parent.OwnerA__c =  terriToOwner.get(taa.Id);
                            if(a.OwnerA__c == null) {
                             a.OwnerA__c =  terriToOwner.get(taa.Id);    
                            }
                        }         
                        if(taa.Brand__c.contains('A') && taa.POR__c == POR_SALES_CONTROL){
                            a.OwnerA__c =  terriToOwner.get(taa.Id); 
                        }
                        
                        if(taa.Brand__c.contains('B') && taa.POR__c == POR_GLOBAL_ACCOUNT_OWNER){
                            a.Parent.OwnerB__c =  terriToOwner.get(taa.Id);
                            if(a.OwnerB__c == null) {
                                a.OwnerB__c =  terriToOwner.get(taa.Id); 
                            }
                        }         
                        if(taa.Brand__c.contains('B') && taa.POR__c == POR_SALES_CONTROL){
                            a.OwnerB__c =  terriToOwner.get(taa.Id); 
                        }
                        
                        if(taa.Brand__c.contains('C') && taa.POR__c == POR_GLOBAL_ACCOUNT_OWNER){
                            a.Parent.OwnerA__c =  terriToOwner.get(taa.Id);
                            if(a.OwnerA__c == null) {
                                a.OwnerA__c =  terriToOwner.get(taa.Id); 
                            }
                        }         
                        if(taa.Brand__c.contains('C') && taa.POR__c == POR_SALES_CONTROL){
                            a.OwnerA__c =  terriToOwner.get(taa.Id); 
                        }
                        
                        if(taa.Brand__c.contains('D') && taa.POR__c == POR_GLOBAL_ACCOUNT_OWNER){
                            a.Parent.OwnerD__c =  terriToOwner.get(taa.Id);
                            if(a.OwnerD__c == null) {
                                a.OwnerD__c =  terriToOwner.get(taa.Id); 
                            }
                        }         
                        if(taa.Brand__c.contains('D') && taa.POR__c == POR_SALES_CONTROL){
                            a.OwnerD__c =  terriToOwner.get(taa.Id); 
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                lstAccount.add(a);
                lstAccount.add(a.Parent);
            }   
       system.debug('lstAccount ' + lstAccount);
    update lstAccount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the techniques covered in [this canonical Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records)?

Comment: Hi Phil.. I have seen those.. but it will be really helpful if i get some guidelines or direction in terms of my code

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to run faster, I don't see where a map will help.
However:

1. Using "else if" instead of "if" allows the compiler to execute the first if statement that is true and to exclude the rest of the criteria - which will speed up your code.
2. I'm not sure why there's a set declared as a class variable when you only use it in one method; I think you'll save time by declaring and using it in the method. In general, variables should be declared and used as locally as possible.
3. If you happen to pass an Account and its parent into this class, everything fails because you'll have the same record in there twice. Instead of adding the Accounts to a list, add them to a map (by AccountId) and then you may need to check if it's there, etc. in case you find the Account and its parent, or you may just overwrite it without checking - that's up to you and your logic.