# Getting variable value from For-Loop and want to bind that value to where clause in SOQL query and further evaluation of code

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I know I can't write list in for loop, what would be another way to implement this scenario where I have to pass the variable value in where clause and I have another for loop where I have to retrieve value from that list accordingly to tempGender value.

```
    for(Contact ThisContact: contactList){
        tempGender = ThisContact.Salutation;

        List<npct1_FC_Gender__mdt> FCGenderList =new List<npct1_FC_Gender__mdt>
                                                           ([SELECT npct1_Gender_Pick__c, npct1_Addressee_Salutation__c
                                                            FROM npct1_FC_Gender__mdt
                                                            WHERE npct1_Gender_Pick__c = :tempGender
                                                            ]);
        for(npct1_FC_Building_Block__mdt ThisBuilingBlock :FCBuildingBlockList)
        {
    
           resultString = FCGenderList.get('npct1_Gender_Pick__c') +resultString;
           // further code
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code, but creating a list (or any other collection) inside of a loop is not one of them. It's the *query* inside the loop that's the issue.

+edit: Queries for Custom Metadata Types don't count towards the SOQL query limit (though the rows are still counted towards the row limit). That said, it's still a good idea to keep queries outside of loops. End edit.

The standard fix for this is to loop over `contactList` and gather data to be used in the query (see [How do I bulkify queries for directly or indirectly related records?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records)), but given you're querying for salutations this is probably not worth it (you'd have what, 3 or 4 different salutations at most?).

If this were an SObject, I'd just tell you to query them all (i.e. have no `WHERE` clause).

You're working with a custom metadata type though. There's little reason for you to write a query here at all. Instead, you should be using the `.getAll()` method (e.g. `npct1_FC_Gender__mdt.getAll()`). Doing this pulls the information from the application cache (which is about 7x faster than getting the information from a query). As long as you don't have/need more than 255 characters from any particular field, `.getAll()` is the way to go.

Your inner loop is also problematic.

`FCGenderList.get('npct1_Gender_Pick__c')` is not valid syntax for a list. It *could* be valid syntax for a map, but you're treating the resulting object as if it were a string (which it isn't). You also seem to be setting yourself up for the typical "nested loop to find a matching record" anti-pattern which looks like

```java
// This is bad code, and it should not be used
// If you find yourself writing code like this, you should use a Map instead
for(Object1__c obj1 :obj1List){
    for(Object2__c obj2 :obj2List){
        if(obj1.Field__c == obj2.Field__c){
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

The much better approach is to separate the loops, and build a map.

```java
// The map key doesn't need to be of type string, I'm just using that for sake of example
Map<String, Object2__c> obj2FieldToObj2 = new Map<String, Object2__c>();

for(Object2__c obj2 :obj2List){
    obj2FieldToObj2.put(obj2.Target_Field__c, obj2);
}

for(Object1__c obj1 :obj1List){
    // Now that the map has been populated, you can use it here instead of using
    //   a nested loop to try to find one matching record
    Object2 matchedObj = obj2FieldToObj2.get(obj1.Matching_Field__c);

    // It's possible that there was no match, so you'll want to perform a null check before
    //   using the data you fetched from the map
    if(matchedObj == null){
        // "continue" causes the rest of the loop to be skipped and for you to
        //   start working on the next item in the list
        continue;
    }

    // If we get here, then it's safe to use matchedObj
}
```

In your specific case, your map key would be a string. You'd iterate over your custom metadata type records and use `npct1_Gender_Pick__c` as the map key.

Your loop over contacts would then start like this

```java
for(Contact workingContact: contactList){
    // This single line removes the need for the query you previously had
    npct1_FC_Gender__mdt genderMDTRecord = myMDTMap.get(workingContact.Saluation);

    // not enough context to say what you'd do after this point...
}
```

Comment: Query against custom metadata in a loop isn't _necessarily_ an issue. The rows still count, but not the queries themselves.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I was under the impression that querying bypassed the application cache and thus counted towards the query count. It appears I mixed up custom setting and custom metadata type behavior.