# Need to insert New Event Date and time in Account Field (Event Date Time (manually created)) through Apex Class/Trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, after-trigger

I am trying to insert **New Event** Start date/time and End date/time in Account object field (Event Date Time). Please help me to trigger code.

Once New Event created, the Start Date/Time & End date/Time visible in Account Object (field name is 'Event Date Time' Field **Data type** is Date/Time). Anyone please help me.

Below is my code. In this i am not able to update Start Date/Time and End Date/Time in one field. Also Particular detail is updating in all Account but i want to update this in particular One account. I am new in salesforce developer.

```java
trigger EventDateTime on Event (after insert, after update) {
    List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id, Event_Date_Time__c from Account ];
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
        for (Event Ev : Trigger.new){
            for (Account a : acc){
                a.Event_Date_Time__c =  Ev.StartDateTime;
                a.Event_Date_Time__c = Ev.EndDate;
            }
        }
        update acc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to create a new field, or add data into an existing field? [Edit] your question to show us what you've tried and point to a specific place that you're stuck on. If you're new to Salesforce, then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to get you started.

Comment: i want to insert New Event 'Start date/time and End date/time'. i already created Field Label (Event Date Time) in Account object. want to insert New Event time in this field with the help of trigger. Once New Event created, the Start Date/Time & End date/Time visible in Account Object field 'Event Date Time Field'.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question to show your code. Please note that SFSE won't make the required changes for you - we'll help you solve a specific problem, but you need to write the actual code. I've removed that request from the question.

Comment: One of the patterns from [this canonical QA](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) will take you where you need to go, but what you're doing is essentially writing a rollup trigger. That is fairly complex for a new developer, and will take some work understanding the data model and Apex best practices in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot we don't know based on the information you provided above, but here are some things to get you headed in the right direction:

- Your current code is updating *all* Accounts because that is exactly what you are telling it to do. You are selecting all Accounts into "acc" and then looping over that entire collection for each updated or inserted Event. Somehow you need to determine *which* Account exactly you want to update for each Event.
- If we can assume that the Account is related to the Event in a normal way then the standard AccountId on each Event should point to the related Account.  This is the Account you want to update for each Event being processed.
- If the above is true, then you can use a handy feature of Apex sObjects and can create a new Account instance, set its' id to the AccountId from the event, set the two fields you want to set, and then add it to your List to update outside the loop. You don't actually have to select the underlying account to do this.

Something like:

```
trigger EventDateTime on Event (after insert, after update) {
    List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
        for (Event Ev : Trigger.new){
            if (Ev.AccountId != null) {
                Account toUpdate = new Account();
                toUpdate.Id = Ev.AccountId;
                toUpdate.Event_Date_Time__c =  Ev.StartDateTime;
                // the below won't work, we assume you have another custom field for end?
                // toUpdate.Event_Date_Time__c = Ev.EndDate;
                acc.add(toUpdate);
            }
        }
        update acc;
    }
}
```

NOTE that there are some other issues in your code above, and I wouldn't do this work directly in the Trigger anyway (see something like https://github.com/trailheadapps/apex-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/classes/Trigger%20Recipes/MetadataTriggerHandler.cls)...

Comment: A few additional things to note here.  1) It's impossible to have a single field (`Event_Date_Time__c`) store two distinct values (`ev.StartDateTime` and `ev.EndDate`) unless it's a text or multipicklist. Even then, a straight assignment instead of appending will simply overwrite the values. 2) You need to take care to not have the `acc` list contain duplicate Ids. In the end, this is far beyond OP's abilities.

Comment: Oops, yeah I just copied / pasted some of the code and didn't look that carefully!

Comment: Thanks  Matt Comer sir.. code is working for me. Thanks a lot this help me in my learning.