# Avoid query inside for in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, query, map

Hi I am new at Salesforce I did a LWC form that creates a record. Some fields of this record can´t be filled by the user so I did a Trigger for the custom object that creates this record.

The problem is that when the Trigger is activated it gets the user info to find by a query the contact of this user. And then from this contact record I have to query other objects. I know that using queries inside for because of the DML limits. I was wondering if anybody could make an example lime mine trying to solve my problem.

My code is this one:

```
if(Trigger.isInsert){
if(Trigger.isAfter){

    List<Mi_entregable__c> lista = new List<Mi_entregable__c>();
    User user = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM User WHERE id =: userinfo.getuserid()];
    System.debug( 'User Id ' + user.Id );
    Contact contact = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email =: user.Email];
    System.debug( 'Contact Email: ' + contact.Email);


    for(Mi_entregable__c a: Trigger.new){
        System.debug('(From Trigger)id is: ' + a.Id); //Id from the record that has been created by the user in the LWC form
        System.debug('(From Trigger)name is : ' + a.Name);
        //Query 1
        Mi_entregable__c m = [SELECT Id, Name, Student__c, mySubject__c FROM Mi_entregable__c WHERE Id =: a.Id];
        m.Student__c = contact.Id;
        String alumnoId = contact.Id;
        String IdEntregableCurso = m.Entregable_del_curso__c.Id; 
        //Query 2
        Entregable_del_Curso__c e = [SELECT Id, Name, Course_Subject__c FROM Entregable_del_Curso__c WHERE Id =: IdEntregableCurso];
        String IdCourseSubject = e.Course_Subject__c.Id;
        //Query 3
        My_subject__c s = [SELECT Id, Name, Student__c, Course_Subject__c FROM My_subject__c WHERE Student__c =: alumnoId 
                            AND Course_Subject__c =: IdCourseSubject ];
        //assig the query data in their fields
        
        m.mySubject__c = s.Id;
        lista.add(m);
        update lista;
     }
}
```

}

Also when I tried to deploy this class I had the next error: **A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: Entregable_del_curso__c (20:46)**
In the line 20 I am getting the id of of the field that was inserted in the apex class that I used in the LWC form so the id exists.

Thanks

Comment: The search term you need here is "bulk" or "bulkify".  There are many good tutorials and videos on bulk Apex / SOQL, like this [Salesforce Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk).

Comment: See this [canonical answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) for another starting point.