# How to resolve too many SOQL after using Handler

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, dml

I am using Trigger Handler for my Trigger. But still getting Too many SOQL on updateNoMaterialTool(); &
**Apex Class**

```
public class ProjectTriggerHandler {
    public Map<Id, Projects__c> oldProjectMap {get;set;}
    public Map<Id, Projects__c> newProjectMap {get;set;}
    public Map<String, String> rejectedFieldToTargetPicklistMap {get;set;}
    public ProjectTriggerHandler(Map<Id, Projects__c> oldProjectMapParam, Map<Id, Projects__c> newProjectMapParam) {
        this.oldProjectMap = oldProjectMapParam;
        this.newProjectMap = newProjectMapParam;
    }
    public void operationBeforeUpdate() {
        updateRejectedPickListValues();
         //Exisitng trigger code added here
        updateNoMaterialTool();
    }
    public void operationBeforeInsert() {
        //Exisitng trigger code added here
        updateNoMaterialTool();
    }

    public void updateNoMaterialTool() {

        List<Project_Items__c> projectItemList=new  List<Project_Items__c>();
        List<Tools_Master__c> toolList=new  List<Tools_Master__c>();
        
        List<Projects__c> UpdateProject=new  List<Projects__c>();
        for( Projects__c pro: newProjectMap.values() ){
            
            projectItemList=[select id,Name,Execution__r.Name,Total_GRPO_Quantity__c,Execution__r.Project__c,Execution__r.Project__r.LL_Location__c,Item_Description__c,SAP_Item_Code__c,Item_Group_Name__c,
                                                    Approved_Make__c,UOM__c,Total_Initial_Stock__c,Total_Billed_Quantity__c,Total_Remaining_Stock__c from Project_Items__c 
                                                    where(Execution__r.Project__c =:pro.id )
                                                    AND Total_Remaining_Stock__c > 0];
            
            system.debug('projectItemList'+projectItemList);
            
            toolList=[select id,Tool_ID__c,Name,Tool_Description__c,Make__c,Region__c,Serial_Number__c,Procured_Date__c,
                                                    Tool_Status__c,Warehouse_Name__c,Calibration_Certificate_URL__c,Project_Names__c from Tools_Master__c 
                                                    where Project_Names__c =:pro.Opportunity_ID__c];
            
            system.debug('toolList'+ toolList);
            
                if( projectItemList.isEmpty() ){
                if(toolList.isEmpty()){
                        pro.No_Material_to_Return_Tools__c=true;
                    }
                }
            if( projectItemList.isEmpty() ){
                if(!toolList.isEmpty()){
                        pro.No_Material_to_Return_Tools__c=false;
                    }   
            }
            
            if(! projectItemList.isEmpty() ){
                if(toolList.isEmpty()){
                        pro.No_Material_to_Return_Tools__c=false;
                    }   
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    private void checkAndUpdateRevisionEHS(Projects__c oldRec, Projects__c newRec) {
        System.debug('@@@@@@ 1 @@@@@@ '+oldRec.Client_Approval_Status_EHS__c );
        System.debug('@@@@@@ 2 @@@@@@ '+newRec.Client_Approval_Status_EHS__c );
        System.debug('@@@@@@ 3 @@@@@@ '+oldRec.Revision_EHS__c );
        System.debug('@@@@@@ 4 @@@@@@ '+newRec.Revision_EHS__c );
        if(oldRec.Client_Approval_Status_EHS__c != newRec.Client_Approval_Status_EHS__c && 
                    newRec.Client_Approval_Status_EHS__c == 'Rejected') {
            if(oldRec.Revision_EHS__c == 'R10')
            {
                System.debug('@@@@@@ 5 @@@@@@ ');
                return;
            }
            String oldRevisionVal =oldRec.Revision_EHS__c;
            System.debug('@@@@@@ 6 @@@@@@ '+oldRevisionVal);
            String trailingIntegerString =  oldRevisionVal.subString(oldRevisionVal.length()-1, oldRevisionVal.length()); 
            System.debug('@@@@@@ 7 @@@@@@ '+trailingIntegerString);
            Integer incrementedTrail = Integer.valueOf(trailingIntegerString) + 1;
            System.debug('@@@@@@ 8 @@@@@@ '+incrementedTrail);
            newRec.Revision_EHS__c = 'R'+incrementedTrail;    
            System.debug('@@@@@@ 9 @@@@@@ '+newRec.Revision_EHS__c);       
        }
    }
    
    private void checkAndUpdateRevisionQuality(Projects__c oldRec, Projects__c newRec) {
        if(oldRec.Clients_Approval_Status_quality__c != newRec.Clients_Approval_Status_quality__c && 
                    newRec.Clients_Approval_Status_quality__c == 'Rejected') {
            if(oldRec.Revision__c == 'R10')
            {
                return;
            }
            String oldRevisionVal =oldRec.Revision__c;
            String trailingIntegerString =  oldRevisionVal.subString(oldRevisionVal.length()-1, oldRevisionVal.length()); 
            Integer incrementedTrail = Integer.valueOf(trailingIntegerString) + 1;
            newRec.Revision__c = 'R'+incrementedTrail;           
        }
        
    }
    private void checkAndUpdateRevisionTCC(Projects__c oldRec, Projects__c newRec) {
         if(oldRec.Clients_Approval_StatusT_C__c != newRec.Clients_Approval_StatusT_C__c && 
                    newRec.Clients_Approval_StatusT_C__c == 'Rejected') {
            if(oldRec.Revision_T_C__c == 'R10')
            {
                return;
            }
            String oldRevisionVal =oldRec.Revision_T_C__c;
            String trailingIntegerString =  oldRevisionVal.subString(oldRevisionVal.length()-1, oldRevisionVal.length()); 
            Integer incrementedTrail = Integer.valueOf(trailingIntegerString) + 1;
            newRec.Revision_T_C__c = 'R'+incrementedTrail;           
        }

    }
    private void checkAndUpdateRevisionSLogis(Projects__c oldRec, Projects__c newRec) {
         if(oldRec.X9_Clients_Approval_Status_S_Logis__c!= newRec.X9_Clients_Approval_Status_S_Logis__c && 
                    newRec.X9_Clients_Approval_Status_S_Logis__c == 'Rejected') {
            if(oldRec.X2_Revision_S_Logis__c == 'R10')
            {
                return;
            }
            String oldRevisionVal =oldRec.X2_Revision_S_Logis__c;
            String trailingIntegerString =  oldRevisionVal.subString(oldRevisionVal.length()-1, oldRevisionVal.length()); 
            Integer incrementedTrail = Integer.valueOf(trailingIntegerString) + 1;
            newRec.X2_Revision_S_Logis__c = 'R'+incrementedTrail;           
        }
        
    }
    
    private void checkAndUpdateRevisionProjectSchedule(Projects__c oldRec, Projects__c newRec) {
        if(oldRec.Client_Approval_Status_Project_Schedule__c != newRec.Client_Approval_Status_Project_Schedule__c && 
                    newRec.Client_Approval_Status_Project_Schedule__c == 'Rejected') {
            if(oldRec.Revision_Project_Schedule__c == 'R10')
            {
                return;
            }
            String oldRevisionVal =oldRec.Revision_Project_Schedule__c;
            String trailingIntegerString =  oldRevisionVal.subString(oldRevisionVal.length()-1, oldRevisionVal.length()); 
            Integer incrementedTrail = Integer.valueOf(trailingIntegerString) + 1;
            newRec.Revision_Project_Schedule__c = 'R'+incrementedTrail;           
        }
        
    }
    private void checkAndUpdateRevisionToolsAndTackles(Projects__c oldRec, Projects__c newRec) {
        if(oldRec.Project_Lead_s_Approval_Status_TTP__c != newRec.Project_Lead_s_Approval_Status_TTP__c && 
                    newRec.Project_Lead_s_Approval_Status_TTP__c == 'Rejected') {
            if(oldRec.Revision_Tools_and_Tackles_Plan__c == 'R10')
            {
                return;
            }
            String oldRevisionVal =oldRec.Revision_Tools_and_Tackles_Plan__c;
            String trailingIntegerString =  oldRevisionVal.subString(oldRevisionVal.length()-1, oldRevisionVal.length()); 
            Integer incrementedTrail = Integer.valueOf(trailingIntegerString) + 1;
            newRec.Revision_Tools_and_Tackles_Plan__c = 'R'+incrementedTrail;           
        }
        
        
    }
    private void updateRejectedPickListValues() {
        for(Projects__c oldRec : oldProjectMap.values()) {
            Projects__c newRec = newProjectMap.get(oldRec.Id);
            checkAndUpdateRevisionEHS(oldRec, newRec);
            checkAndUpdateRevisionQuality(oldRec, newRec);
            checkAndUpdateRevisionTCC(oldRec, newRec);
            checkAndUpdateRevisionSLogis(oldRec, newRec);
            checkAndUpdateRevisionProjectSchedule(oldRec, newRec);
            checkAndUpdateRevisionToolsAndTackles(oldRec, newRec);
        }
    }
}
```

**NEW CODE**

```
public class ProjectTriggerHandler {
    public Map<Id, Projects__c> oldProjectMap {get;set;}
    public Map<Id, Projects__c> newProjectMap {get;set;}
    public Map<String, String> rejectedFieldToTargetPicklistMap {get;set;}
    
    public ProjectTriggerHandler(Map<Id, Projects__c> oldProjectMapParam, Map<Id, Projects__c> newProjectMapParam) {
        this.oldProjectMap = oldProjectMapParam;
        this.newProjectMap = newProjectMapParam;
    }
    public void operationBeforeUpdate() {
        updateRejectedPickListValues();
         //Exisitng trigger code added here
        //updateNoMaterialTool();
    }
    public void operationBeforeInsert() {
        //Exisitng trigger code added here
        //updateNoMaterialTool();
    }

    public void updateNoMaterialTool() {
    
    List<Projects__c> UpdateProject=new  List<Projects__c>();
    
    Set<Id> projectsIds = newProjectMap.keySet();
    List<Project_Items__c> projectItemList=[select id,Name,Execution__r.Name,Total_GRPO_Quantity__c,Execution__r.Project__c,Execution__r.Project__r.LL_Location__c,Item_Description__c,SAP_Item_Code__c,Item_Group_Name__c,
                                                Approved_Make__c,UOM__c,Total_Initial_Stock__c,Total_Billed_Quantity__c,Total_Remaining_Stock__c from Project_Items__c 
                                                where(Execution__r.Project__c IN :projectsIds )
                                                AND Total_Remaining_Stock__c > 0];
                                                
    system.debug('projectItemList'+projectItemList);
    
    Set<String> opportunitiesIds = collectSobjectsFieldValues(newProjectMap.values(), 'Opportunity_ID__c');
    List<Tools_Master__c> toolList=[select id,Tool_ID__c,Name,Tool_Description__c,Make__c,Region__c,Serial_Number__c,Procured_Date__c,
                                                Tool_Status__c,Warehouse_Name__c,Calibration_Certificate_URL__c,Project_Names__c from Tools_Master__c 
                                                where Project_Names__c IN :opportunitiesIds];
                                                
    system.debug('toolList'+ toolList);
                                                
    for( Projects__c pro: newProjectMap.values() ){
            if( projectItemList.isEmpty() ){
            if(toolList.isEmpty()){
                    pro.No_Material_to_Return_Tools__c=true;
                }
            }
        if( projectItemList.isEmpty() ){
            if(!toolList.isEmpty()){
                    pro.No_Material_to_Return_Tools__c=false;
                }   
        }
        
        if(! projectItemList.isEmpty() ){
            if(toolList.isEmpty()){
                    pro.No_Material_to_Return_Tools__c=false;
                }   
        }
        
    }
}

private Set<String> collectSobjectsFieldValues(List<SObject> sobjectList, String fieldName) {
    Set<String> result = new Set<String>();
    for(SObject record: sobjectList) {
        result.add((String)record.get(fieldName));
    }
    
    return result;
}
 
    private void checkAndUpdateRevisionEHS(Projects__c oldRec, Projects__c newRec) {
        System.debug('@@@@@@ 1 @@@@@@ '+oldRec.Client_Approval_Status_EHS__c );
        System.debug('@@@@@@ 2 @@@@@@ '+newRec.Client_Approval_Status_EHS__c );
        System.debug('@@@@@@ 3 @@@@@@ '+oldRec.Revision_EHS__c );
        System.debug('@@@@@@ 4 @@@@@@ '+newRec.Revision_EHS__c );
        if(oldRec.Client_Approval_Status_EHS__c != newRec.Client_Approval_Status_EHS__c && 
                    newRec.Client_Approval_Status_EHS__c == 'Rejected') {
            if(oldRec.Revision_EHS__c == 'R10')
            {
                System.debug('@@@@@@ 5 @@@@@@ ');
                return;
            }
            String oldRevisionVal =oldRec.Revision_EHS__c;
            System.debug('@@@@@@ 6 @@@@@@ '+oldRevisionVal);
            String trailingIntegerString =  oldRevisionVal.subString(oldRevisionVal.length()-1, oldRevisionVal.length()); 
            System.debug('@@@@@@ 7 @@@@@@ '+trailingIntegerString);
            Integer incrementedTrail = Integer.valueOf(trailingIntegerString) + 1;
            System.debug('@@@@@@ 8 @@@@@@ '+incrementedTrail);
            newRec.Revision_EHS__c = 'R'+incrementedTrail;    
            System.debug('@@@@@@ 9 @@@@@@ '+newRec.Revision_EHS__c);       
        }
    }
    
    private void checkAndUpdateRevisionQuality(Projects__c oldRec, Projects__c newRec) {
        if(oldRec.Clients_Approval_Status_quality__c != newRec.Clients_Approval_Status_quality__c && 
                    newRec.Clients_Approval_Status_quality__c == 'Rejected') {
            if(oldRec.Revision__c == 'R10')
            {
                return;
            }
            String oldRevisionVal =oldRec.Revision__c;
            String trailingIntegerString =  oldRevisionVal.subString(oldRevisionVal.length()-1, oldRevisionVal.length()); 
            Integer incrementedTrail = Integer.valueOf(trailingIntegerString) + 1;
            newRec.Revision__c = 'R'+incrementedTrail;           
        }
        
    }
    private void checkAndUpdateRevisionTCC(Projects__c oldRec, Projects__c newRec) {
         if(oldRec.Clients_Approval_StatusT_C__c != newRec.Clients_Approval_StatusT_C__c && 
                    newRec.Clients_Approval_StatusT_C__c == 'Rejected') {
            if(oldRec.Revision_T_C__c == 'R10')
            {
                return;
            }
            String oldRevisionVal =oldRec.Revision_T_C__c;
            String trailingIntegerString =  oldRevisionVal.subString(oldRevisionVal.length()-1, oldRevisionVal.length()); 
            Integer incrementedTrail = Integer.valueOf(trailingIntegerString) + 1;
            newRec.Revision_T_C__c = 'R'+incrementedTrail;           
        }

    }
    private void checkAndUpdateRevisionSLogis(Projects__c oldRec, Projects__c newRec) {
         if(oldRec.X9_Clients_Approval_Status_S_Logis__c!= newRec.X9_Clients_Approval_Status_S_Logis__c && 
                    newRec.X9_Clients_Approval_Status_S_Logis__c == 'Rejected') {
            if(oldRec.X2_Revision_S_Logis__c == 'R10')
            {
                return;
            }
            String oldRevisionVal =oldRec.X2_Revision_S_Logis__c;
            String trailingIntegerString =  oldRevisionVal.subString(oldRevisionVal.length()-1, oldRevisionVal.length()); 
            Integer incrementedTrail = Integer.valueOf(trailingIntegerString) + 1;
            newRec.X2_Revision_S_Logis__c = 'R'+incrementedTrail;           
        }
        
    }
    
    private void checkAndUpdateRevisionProjectSchedule(Projects__c oldRec, Projects__c newRec) {
        if(oldRec.Client_Approval_Status_Project_Schedule__c != newRec.Client_Approval_Status_Project_Schedule__c && 
                    newRec.Client_Approval_Status_Project_Schedule__c == 'Rejected') {
            if(oldRec.Revision_Project_Schedule__c == 'R10')
            {
                return;
            }
            String oldRevisionVal =oldRec.Revision_Project_Schedule__c;
            String trailingIntegerString =  oldRevisionVal.subString(oldRevisionVal.length()-1, oldRevisionVal.length()); 
            Integer incrementedTrail = Integer.valueOf(trailingIntegerString) + 1;
            newRec.Revision_Project_Schedule__c = 'R'+incrementedTrail;           
        }
        
    }
    private void checkAndUpdateRevisionToolsAndTackles(Projects__c oldRec, Projects__c newRec) {
        if(oldRec.Project_Lead_s_Approval_Status_TTP__c != newRec.Project_Lead_s_Approval_Status_TTP__c && 
                    newRec.Project_Lead_s_Approval_Status_TTP__c == 'Rejected') {
            if(oldRec.Revision_Tools_and_Tackles_Plan__c == 'R10')
            {
                return;
            }
            String oldRevisionVal =oldRec.Revision_Tools_and_Tackles_Plan__c;
            String trailingIntegerString =  oldRevisionVal.subString(oldRevisionVal.length()-1, oldRevisionVal.length()); 
            Integer incrementedTrail = Integer.valueOf(trailingIntegerString) + 1;
            newRec.Revision_Tools_and_Tackles_Plan__c = 'R'+incrementedTrail;           
        }
        
        
    }
    private void updateRejectedPickListValues() {
        for(Projects__c oldRec : oldProjectMap.values()) {
            Projects__c newRec = newProjectMap.get(oldRec.Id);
            checkAndUpdateRevisionEHS(oldRec, newRec);
            checkAndUpdateRevisionQuality(oldRec, newRec);
            checkAndUpdateRevisionTCC(oldRec, newRec);
            checkAndUpdateRevisionSLogis(oldRec, newRec);
            checkAndUpdateRevisionProjectSchedule(oldRec, newRec);
            checkAndUpdateRevisionToolsAndTackles(oldRec, newRec);
        }
    }
}
```

**Trigger**

```
trigger ProjectTrigger on Projects__c (before insert, before update) {
    ProjectTriggerHandler handler = new ProjectTriggerHandler(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore) {
        handler.operationBeforeInsert();
    }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore) {
        handler.operationBeforeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see SOQLs in for loops, get them out of the loops.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason of the "Too many SOQL" Exception is SOQLs inside for loop:

```
projectItemList=[select id,Name,Execution__r.Name,Total_GRPO_Quantity__c,Execution__r.Project__c,Execution__r.Project__r.LL_Location__c,Item_Description__c,SAP_Item_Code__c,Item_Group_Name__c,
                                                Approved_Make__c,UOM__c,Total_Initial_Stock__c,Total_Billed_Quantity__c,Total_Remaining_Stock__c from Project_Items__c 
                                                where(Execution__r.Project__c =:pro.id )
                                                AND Total_Remaining_Stock__c > 0];
        
        
toolList=[select id,Tool_ID__c,Name,Tool_Description__c,Make__c,Region__c,Serial_Number__c,Procured_Date__c,
                                                Tool_Status__c,Warehouse_Name__c,Calibration_Certificate_URL__c,Project_Names__c from Tools_Master__c 
                                                where Project_Names__c =:pro.Opportunity_ID__c];
```

You have to make SOQL outside for loop.

```
Set<Id> projectsIds = newProjectMap.keySet();

projectItemList=[select id,Name,Execution__r.Name,Total_GRPO_Quantity__c,Execution__r.Project__c,Execution__r.Project__r.LL_Location__c,Item_Description__c,SAP_Item_Code__c,Item_Group_Name__c,
                                                Approved_Make__c,UOM__c,Total_Initial_Stock__c,Total_Billed_Quantity__c,Total_Remaining_Stock__c from Project_Items__c 
                                                where(Execution__r.Project__c IN :proIds  )
                                                AND Total_Remaining_Stock__c > 0];
```

Make the same with another SOQL but you need to collect pro.Opportunity_ID__c to separate collection and use in WHERE statement

I would also advice you to check [Apex Best Practices](https://www.salesforceben.com/12-salesforce-apex-best-practices/) not to face that kind of issues again

Comment: Can you elaborate the solution on code. So, I can understand better & Can I call this method in future?????? if yes then how?

Comment: @apz The main point to realize here is that you should be gathering data to feed into your queries first. This allows you to remove the queries from the loops. Instead of `where Execution__r.Project__c = :pro.id ` (`pro` being the loop variable), you could do that outside of the loop by making the filter `where Execution__r.Project__c IN :newProjectMap.keySet()`. See [How do I bulkify queries for directly or indirectly related records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: I tried but getting same error. Can you modify the code. So, I can understand were I Did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try  to replace updateNoMaterialTool method with this:

```
public void updateNoMaterialTool() {
    
    List<Projects__c> UpdateProject=new  List<Projects__c>();
    
    Set<Id> projectsIds = newProjectMap.keySet();
    List<Project_Items__c> projectItemList=[select id,Name,Execution__r.Name,Total_GRPO_Quantity__c,Execution__r.Project__c,Execution__r.Project__r.LL_Location__c,Item_Description__c,SAP_Item_Code__c,Item_Group_Name__c,
                                                Approved_Make__c,UOM__c,Total_Initial_Stock__c,Total_Billed_Quantity__c,Total_Remaining_Stock__c from Project_Items__c 
                                                where(Execution__r.Project__c IN :projectsIds )
                                                AND Total_Remaining_Stock__c > 0];
                                                
    system.debug('projectItemList'+projectItemList);
    
    Set<String> opportunitiesIds = collectSobjectsFieldValues(newProjectMap.values(), 'Opportunity_ID__c');
    List<Tools_Master__c> toolList=[select id,Tool_ID__c,Name,Tool_Description__c,Make__c,Region__c,Serial_Number__c,Procured_Date__c,
                                                Tool_Status__c,Warehouse_Name__c,Calibration_Certificate_URL__c,Project_Names__c from Tools_Master__c 
                                                where Project_Names__c IN :opportunitiesIds];
                                                
    system.debug('toolList'+ toolList);
                                                
    for( Projects__c pro: newProjectMap.values() ){
            if( projectItemList.isEmpty() ){
            if(toolList.isEmpty()){
                    pro.No_Material_to_Return_Tools__c=true;
                }
            }
        if( projectItemList.isEmpty() ){
            if(!toolList.isEmpty()){
                    pro.No_Material_to_Return_Tools__c=false;
                }   
        }
        
        if(! projectItemList.isEmpty() ){
            if(toolList.isEmpty()){
                    pro.No_Material_to_Return_Tools__c=false;
                }   
        }
        
    }
}

private Set<String> collectSobjectsFieldValues(List<SObject> sobjectList, String fieldName) {
    Set<String> result = new Set<String>();
    for(SObject record: sobjectList) {
        result.add((String)record.get(fieldName));
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

I made it in notepad. This peace of code can have errors

Comment: Set<String> opportunitiesIds = collectSobjectsFieldValues(newProjectMap.values(), 'Opportunity_ID__c'); having error Illegal assignment from Set<Object> to Set<String>

Comment: Update the row, the new version is:
Set<String> opportunitiesIds = (Set<String>)collectSobjectsFieldValues(newProjectMap.values(), 'Opportunity_ID__c');

Comment: Incompatible types since an instance of Set<Object> is never an instance of Set<String> this is the issue I am facing after updating the line.

Comment: I updated code in the answer, could you please try to it?

Comment: Still showing Too many SOQL "Class.ProjectTriggerHandler.updateNoMaterialTool: line 24, column 1
Class.ProjectTriggerHandler.operationBeforeUpdate: line 12, column 1
Trigger.ProjectTrigger: line 7, column 1"

Comment: Could you please share your current code(update the topic or add new answer). Also add bold style for the row 24

Comment: Yes I updated the code under NEW CODE Topic

Comment: Strange. If there are no any other features or code that use SOQL during transaction then it shouldn't be shown. Is this trigger the only functional that executed during transation?

Comment: There are 2-3 apex and flow which is executing.

Comment: Looks like ProjectTriggerHandler is fine now. Could you please check another classes and flow. They might have the same issue

Comment: MANY other flows are running on asyn and apex runs on future methods

Comment: Konstantin Can we convert this into a future method????

Comment: Yes, I think so, but future methods can use primitive data types parameters only. You need to use List<Id> as a future method parameter. Select records inside updateNoMaterialTool future  and make the same actions with selected data

Comment: Can you help me with the modified code. I have never used and worked on future methods