# Update by SOQL Query in Apex Trigger is not sticking

Tags: trigger, contact, update

I am trying to update a field in the related Account using a apex trigger on the Contact. Here is the code -

```java
trigger AvoidMerge on Contact (before delete) {
    for(Contact contact: trigger.old){
        if(Trigger.isBefore){
            if(Trigger.isDelete){
                if(!String.isBlank(contact.celigo_sfnsio__NetSuite_Id__c)){
                    List<Contact> c = [Select Id, Name, Description, AccountId from Contact where Id = :contact.Id limit 1];
                    if (!c.isEmpty()){      
                        System.debug('Contact update trigger fired '+c[0].AccountId);
                        List<Account> accounts = [Select Id, Name, Description from Account where Id = :c[0].AccountId limit 1];
                        for(Account acc:accounts){
                            acc.Description = 'Updated description';
                        }

                        update accounts;
                        List<Account> temp = [Select Id, Name, Description from Account where Id = :c[0].AccountId limit 1];
                        System.debug('After Contact update trigger fired '+temp[0].Description);
                        contact.adderror('Admin is notified');
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

The two debug statements before and after the update show the required results. However the description field is not updated when I check it using the SOQL in Developer Console. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `contact.adderror('Admin is notified');` this statement causes your entire delete transaction to be rolled back, no Account updates and no Contact deletes.

Comment: Also, queries and dml inside of loops are bad. You could [bulkify them (move them out of the loop(s))](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) but honestly, you don't need to perform any queries here. Trigger context variables (like `trigger.old`) already contain all of the fields on the records going through the trigger, and you can specify the Id when using an SObject's constructor (e.g. `Account myAccount = new Account(Id = contact.Id);`) to avoid those queries as well.