# Work Order Line Items

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to write a trigger that when a new Work Order Line Item gets added, finds a duplicate Work Order Line Item on the same Work Order, adds the new quantity to the existing record and then deletes the new record, otherwise, allows the new record to be created.

The code below works for manual inserts, but doesn't work for bulk inserts, we have a flow that creates around 100 records from a collection, is there a reason why? is it due to the (before insert)?

```
trigger WorkOrderLineItemTrigger on WorkOrderLineItem (before insert) {
    Set<String> newDuplicateKeys = new Set<String>();

    for (WorkOrderLineItem w : Trigger.new) {
        newDuplicateKeys.add(w.Duplicate_Key__c);
    }

    Map<String, WorkOrderLineItem> dbDuplicateKeys = new Map<String, WorkOrderLineItem>();

    for (WorkOrderLineItem w : [SELECT Id, Duplicate_Key__c, Quantity_Installed__c FROM WorkOrderLineItem WHERE Duplicate_Key__c in :newDuplicateKeys]) {
        dbDuplicateKeys.put(w.Duplicate_Key__c, w);
    }

    for (WorkOrderLineItem w : Trigger.new) {
        if (dbDuplicateKeys.containsKey(w.Duplicate_Key__c)) {
            dbDuplicateKeys.get(w.Duplicate_Key__c).Quantity_Installed__c += w.Quantity_Installed__c;
            w.isDuplicate__c = true;
        }
    }

    update dbDuplicateKeys.values();
}
```

Comment: Remember that the duplicates may already be in the database, so you need to both check for duplicates in `Trigger.new`, but also against existing data in the database.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321846/how-do-i-bulkify-queries-for-directly-or-indirectly-related-records) for recommendations around identifier "keys" (specifically to use an Object array rather than string concatenation - it explains why).

Comment: Also, records being inserted aren't going to have Ids in the `before insert` context, so trying to update them would fail. If you're inserting more than 200 records at a time, then duplicates in a different trigger "chunk" would also need to be considered. Fixing the "existing records" logic to be based around a query should also take care of that because I believe that each "chunk" goes through the complete OoO (so `chunk1 before insert -> chunk1 after insert -> chunk2 before insert` rather than `chunk1 before insert -> chunk2 before insert`). Records inserted are queryable in `after insert`.